# É errado perguntar por coisas que se acham facilmente (como alguns julgam) no Google?

Tags: debate, perguntas

É errado perguntar por coisas que se acham no Google facilmente aqui no SOPT?

Porque, na maioria dos casos, o que encontro está sempre em inglês. E além de ter preguiça de ler ter que tentar traduzir o que estou lendo, os navegadores não traduzem perfeitamente o que está sendo dito.

Digo isso porque essa pergunta :

[O que significa NaN no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92169/o-que-significa-nan-no-javascript)

Gerou comentários como esse:

> Sejamos francos, criar uma pergunta como está, é no mínimo implorar por pontos negativos, o google responde isto em fração de segundos.

Comment: Relacionado: [Perguntas feitas sem pesquisa prévia](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4026/3117)

Comment: @Math, só para poder tirar uma dúvida: Esse tipo de comentário realmente deveria estar lá também?

Comment: Em minha opinião ela beira o limite do rude, não acho legal da parte de quem escreveu mas pelo menos me parece um feedback de quem te negativou.

Comment: Eu evitaria comentários como esse. Alguns por aí andaram me zoando porque, depois de uma resposta que eu dei com a frase "Ia dar errado mesmo!", o cara até excluiu a pergunta! rsrsrsrsrs

Comment: Relacionado: [Esclarecer ou fazer o trabalho pelos outros?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157/esclarecer-ou-fazer-o-trabalho-pelos-outros)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não tens sorte nenhuma nas tuas perguntas levas sempre assim uns negativos...

Comment: @JorgeB., achei que a foto do Magneto (o mestre do magnestismo - respeitem-o) iria me dar sorte :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters devias começar a usar do Iron man :)

Comment: Relacionada: [Questão simples demais feita por um “experiente”](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2170/91)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters você é positivo, está atraindo negativos :D

Comment: Puts, os caras conseguiram fazer uma piada com Magneto +1

Comment: valeu @rray. Estou lendo

Comment: Wallace, corrigindo: *"uma piada com Magento"* :)

Comment: Magento? é Magneto mesmo, aquele do X-men, fraga? É a foto que estou usando

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Minha opinião: não é errado postar perguntas simples.

Primeiramente porque o Google só referencia as respostas, elas precisam estar em algum lugar para ser encontradas. E o objetivo do SOPT é *justamente* ser esse lugar em relação ao idioma Português.

Adicionalmente, o comentário (mais pedante com as regras do site do que rude, na minha opinião) ignora o fato de que o conhecimento só se forma a partir de mais conhecimento. Uma resposta aqui poderia unificar fontes diversas, provavelmente encontradas no próprio Google, e assim contribuir para que a informação fosse cada vez mais útil a um maior número de pessoas.

Comment: É isso aí. Os negativos são mais pessoais, mas também não acho que aquela pergunta merece os -6 que tem.

Comment: @bfavaretto Também acho que foram injustos. Mas ai, já é outra discussão né? :)

Comment: Parece que o Efeito Meta já fez seu trabalho +9/-5 por agora

Comment: @bfavaretto Talvez se votar negativo em perguntas que já têm, digamos, -2  "custasse" 1 ponto a quem votar, se evitasse o fenómeno de "voto em cascata"

Comment: Concordo com vc @Luiz Vieira. Não a mau algum fazer uma pergunta simples, ainda mais quando os resultados de pesquisa só apontam para sites em inglês ou até mesmo o SO. Tem muitas pessoas que estão iniciando neste caminhada de bit e não conseguem filtrar o conteúdo de uma pesquisa do Google, é bem melhor elas já serem redirecionadas aqui no SOpt da mais credibilidade a comunidade e também atrai novos usuários.

Comment: Isso mesmo. O SOpt foi feito para responder perguntas

Answer (score 17):

Não é errado questionar, pelo contrário, é **correto**.

Assim você vai ter várias respostas, muitas vezes com pontos de vista diferentes, mesmo que sejam questões técnicas que já estão escritas em algum manual, sempre alguém vai ter um conhecimento agregado a mais para passar, uma experiência extra a observar, além do que, criando uma pergunta, ela já vai estar indexada em mecanismos de buscas e no próprio SOPT, assim outras pessoas poderão encontrar as respostas imediatamente, não importa o quão simples sejam.

Algumas pessoas são exageradas no seu ego e falta de paciência. O tempo que o cidadão perdeu para fazer o comentário desagradável, poderia ser o mesmo que dar uma resposta curta e simples, **IMHO**.

É isso, não deixe de questionar camarada, só assim aprendemos.

Answer (score 12):

Eu já tive respostas mal educadas como essas também por perguntas simples. Alguém me respondeu assim, que eu devesse pesquisar. Eu pergunto? O `SOpt` também não é uma fonte de pesquisa? Procurar na NET e no `SOpt`, não é a mesma coisa? Acho sim, que deve perguntar sim, seja qual for a pergunta. Hoje eu tenho o `SOpt` como minha primeira fonte de pesquisa, por tudo que ele faz, eu acredito nele, ainda que tenha alguns aqui com outro espírito, que com certeza não é o de cooperar e ajudar. Digo por experiência aqui dentro, que a maioria aqui são altruísta, têm o espírito de cooperação e ajuda, somam mais de `90%` esses, ainda que alguns apareçam para fazer ou falar o contrário disso. Há caras aqui que só pensam em voto negativo, não dão nenhuma contribuição a ninguém, essa regra não é geral, mas existe sim esse tipo aqui. Cara, tem dúvida pergunte. Fácil para uns, difícil para outros, a vida é assim.

Comment: Só um adendo, mostrar que você pesquisou antes de perguntar é uma demonstração que você se preocupa com seu trabalho e que valoriza o tempo da outra pessoa que se dispõe a responder. Tem vezes que não dá pra demonstrar pesquisa nenhuma, mas na maior parte das vezes é possível sim. O mais horroroso é responder uma pergunta e receber um comentário "isso eu já testei"... *então porquê diacho não disse antes?*

Answer (score -1):

Para mim o SOPT é uma fonte de pesquisa valiosa na maioria das vezes quando coloco uma dúvida no Google os primeiro resultados são para cá ou para o SO. Então cabe sim perguntas simples e de iniciantes o que não cabe são comentários rudes e inuteis para a pergunta e comunidade