# Quando usar o downvote

Tags: debate, voto-contra

**Quando utilizar o downvote?**

Vi que existe essa carência de esclarecimento a respeito desse assunto, para tentar ajudar a comunidade fiz um levantamento nas outras comunidades da SE para tentar trazer o consenso geral a respeito disso.

Visão geral do downvote (via help SO):

**O que é o downvote?**

Downvote é um recurso que ajuda a comunidade indicar que uma pergunta/resposta foi menos útil.

**Quando devo realizar um downvote?**

Deve-se realizar quando encontrar um post de baixa qualidade, sem esforço de pesquisa e quando a pergunta estiver perigosamente incorreta.

**Como realizar um downvote?**

Basta clicar na seta para baixo do lado da pergunta/resposta.

**Esclarecimentos para a comunidade:**

**Quando realizar um downvote?**

Alguns pontos citados pelo usuário Denis de Bernardy no meta em inglês. (tradução livre)

- Pergunta pobre e/ou má escrita, realizar votedown. (vale usar o bom senso e tentar editar a pergunta para ela ficar mais clara e/ou melhor escrita, caso não seja possível realizar o downvote)
- Código colado sem ajuda para interpretação, um grande volume de código que não é necessário para a pergunta em si, falta de compromisso em ajudar quem quer ler a pergunta a entender facilmente. (downvote)
- Pergunta fora dos padrões da comunidade (downvote)
- Não leu a documentação da linguagem (downvote)
- Não usou o google antes de perguntar. (downvote)

Vale sempre usar o bom senso, e também é educado e mais produtivo indicar o motivo do downvote no comentário para auxiliar o usuário melhorar a resposta/pergunta.

Na opinião de vocês, quando é indicado downvote?

Comment: Eu não concordo com todos esses critérios não!

Comment: Boa, vamos chegar em um consenso. Afinal isso aqui é uma comunidade democratica :)

Comment: Sobre consenso, acho que não combina com democracia. Democracia é quando a minoria aceita que vale o voto da maioria. Se houver consenso, não é mais democracia, é praticamente uma crença. Opinião sobre negativos: para perguntas, o negativo é para quando "a pergunta não mostra  nenhum esforço de pesquisa. Ela não é clara ou não é útil". Para respostas, é quando "a resposta não é útil". Na verdade essa não é a minha opinião, é a dica que tem no _tooltip_ do downvote ;) Diferente delas que são regras do site, tudo [é pessoal](/a/1932/70). Aliás, essa seria a razão de o voto ser individual, não?

Comment: Eu ia fazer um comentário, mas basicamente o @Bacco resumiu o que eu ia dizer "votos são pessoais". E pra complementar, por mais que sejam mal usados, ainda existem situações "ambíguas" e mesmo que quiséssemos por regras, não funcionaria, pois teria quer ser estudado muito primeiro. A única coisa (apesar de muitos discordarem) que acredito que resolveria, seriam os comentários anônimos linkados com os "downvotes", claro que o anonimo seria opcional. Assim o usuário poderia dizer o motivo do downvote sem ter medo de retalhação, pois hoje é isto que impede muitos de comentarem :/

Comment: Recomenda-se um pela manhã, dois ao meio-dia e o da noite é facultativo

Comment: @brasofilo e lembrando que é em horário UTC ;)

Comment: faltou adicionar um dos motivos pelos quais mais usam os downvotes aqui, que é retaliação.. rsrrs... Mas, enfim, não concordo com todos os pontos propostos. Não está ruim, talvez faltou colocar mais detalhes. A opinião que tenho sobre o assunto é bem semelhante a resposta do @Randrade.

Answer (score 16):

## Perguntas

- a pergunta se mostrou irrecuperável, foi fechada e só está atrapalhando no *site*
- sem esforço para elaborar o problema que o autor está tendo (vide detalhes abaixo)
- está pedindo para fazer tudo para ela
- quando ela não é séria (*spam*, *trolagem*, contenha algum tipo de ofensa num sentido amplo)

O português errado não é motivo para negativação, é comum errar. Mas se estiver com uma quantidade absurda de erros, ela se torna incompreensível. Pode ser errado, mas tem que ser em português de verdade.

Quando está incompreensível, a pergunta deve ser fechada como **não clara**. O negativo pode acompanhar posteriormente se nada for feito, quando realmente a pergunta está atrapalhando.

A famosa "falta de pesquisa" se refere mais ao fato da pessoa não ter tentado resolver o problema. Ao contrário da crença popular ela não indica que perguntas simples não podem ser feitas sem problemas.

Não leu a documentação primeiro? Ok, a pessoa pode não saber onde achar a documentação. A documentação pode estar em inglês. Se não tem no SOpt, não tem problema. Se tem, a pergunta pode ser fechada como duplicata e eventualmente pode receber negativos ou não. Nem sempre merece.

Certamente não merece negativos porque tem na documentação.

Não procurou no Google? E daí? Se não tem no SOpt, a pergunta é boa. A ideia é que o Google mostre a resposta do SOpt em primeiro lugar. E só se ela for feita é que terá a resposta.

Negativar por estes motivos impediria, por exemplo, as perguntas que a pessoa já sabe a resposta. E o mecanismo explicitamente incentiva este tipo de pergunta. Então não cabe negativos nestes casos.

A falta de pesquisa tem a ver com o fato da pessoa não tentar fazer nada e querer que resolvam tudo para ela. Isto é mais válido para casos práticos. Perguntas mais conceituais evidentemente isto não cabe tão bem.

Negativo é para indicar que há sérios problemas com a pergunta. É para mostrar que ela tem baixa qualidade, ajudando o mecanismo removê-la no futuro em certas circunstâncias, ou para quem lê ter uma informação que a pergunta tem problemas.

O negativo certamente não é para punir ninguém, ainda que alguns achem que sim. E se o novato acha isto, é um problema no mecanismo principalmente e da comunidade secundariamente, não deixar claro para a pessoa que isto não é uma punição, mostrar que há um motivo para existir uma negativação **do conteúdo**, que pode ser revertido, que não é pessoal, e sim o conteúdo que não está nas melhores condições.

Este é outro ponto importante, o voto negativo ou positivo deve ser em cima do conteúdo e não da pessoa. Deve-se avaliar a qualidade dele, a utilidade que ele terá para as pessoas.

O voto negativo ou positivo não pode ser dado ou deixar de ser dado por causa dos sentimentos das pessoas. É o conteúdo que importa. Por isto ficar compensando votos pode ser mais nefasto ainda. Nunca vote positivo só porque o coitadinho do autor pode se magoar porque recebeu um negativo. Este é o outro lado da moeda de negativar porque você odeia o sujeito que postou algo.

Pode parecer que você está sendo bonzinho quando compensa um negativo, mas está prejudicando a comunidade por glorificar um conteúdo ruim. Note que isto não é o mesmo que positivar algo que está negativo injustamente, que o conteúdo merece receber positivos por méritos próprios.

Não negative se acha que o autor postou só por causa da reputação. Reputação faz parte do mecanismo. A pessoa receberá por postar coisas boas. Não se preocupe com a reputação dos outros, se preocupe com a sua.

Aí chegamos em mais um ponto importante. Julgue a utilidade da pergunta. Se a pergunta não pode ser considerada inútil, provavelmente não merece negativo. As perguntas escritas direitinho, onde a pessoa está se esforçando para ajudar as pessoas ajudarem ela e outras pessoas, não merecem negativo.

Fora os casos de abuso, em geral, conteúdos recebem negativos por causa do seu autor, não há dúvidas disso, mas é o conteúdo que deve ser analisado. Em geral os negativos justos são dados quando a pessoa está sendo teimosa ou não tem nenhuma capacidade de se expressar sobre aquele problema.

É pressuposto básico a pessoa ter um mínimo de capacidade de expressão para fazer uma pergunta e ter a mente aberta às críticas construtivas que receber ou modificações feitas por terceiros. O negativo costuma vir, ou deveria ser assim, quando ela não conseguiu nem escrever uma boa pergunta, nem melhorá-la, nem dar condições que outros o façam. Negativos assim deveriam ser antecedidos por fechamento.

Mas não ache que negativos e fechamentos estão intimamente ligados. Tem coisas que merece permanecer bem no site, ainda que fechados. E existem coisas ruins que não precisam ser fechadas. Nem sempre uma coisa ruim atende os critérios de fechamento.

Os negativos certamente não podem ser dados porque você discorda da pergunta. Ele pode ser dado para uma pergunta com uma premissa errada e que não poderá ser salva. Em geral o negativo é o último recurso para enterrar a pergunta muito ruim.

O fechamento deve ser preferido sempre que possível no lugar do negativo. Uma edição, um comentário para ajudar sempre é preferível. Eu sei que não dá para ter paciência sempre e que há casos que claramente não dá para recuperar. Mas a ação padrão deve ser tentar salvar, depois fechar e negativar nos piores casos, principalmente quando tudo isto falha.

Pergunta fora do padrão da comunidade pra mim, deve ser fechada, ou removida em casos graves. Pra remover, precisa negativar e/ou sinalizar. Mas precisa ser caso que sua presença está prejudicando.

Tenha em mente que estamos aqui para ajudar as pessoas. Pessoas que não dominam o assunto que estão perguntando. Claro que elas também precisam colaborar. Precisam ajudar nós ajudarmos ela. Se a pergunta ajuda pessoas, deixa ela lá. Pode não merecer positivos, mas não merece negativos porque ela é simples, básica, tem resposta em outro lugar, etc.

Eu vejo o entendimento errado de muita gente que aqui temos muitas regras que precisam ser seguidas a qualquer custo. Tem que se perguntar que mal a pergunta faz ao site. Algumas fazem.

Também não deixe de negativar o que precisa ser. Nem tudo é salvável. Abóboras não viram carruagens. Tem coisas que merecem negativo logo, outras precisam dar um tempo.

## Respostas

- está clara e inequivocamente errada, negative.
- é enganosa (leva a pessoa cometer erros fundamentais), pode merecer negativo em alguns raros casos
- plágio. Depende do nível. A maioria não costuma negativar por causa disto, a não ser em casos exagerados.
- abusos verdadeiros (não são respostas de fato: *spam*, *trolagem*, etc. você já sabe) podem não só serem negativadas, como sinalizadas também, e removidas.

Se a resposta é útil para outros, mesmo que seja de outra tecnologia ou não responde diretamente ao problema apresentado, se não contém outros problemas, deixa ela lá. Não precisa positivar se ela está muito fora. Uma solução Java para C# pode não ser útil para o autor mas pode ser para outra pessoas. Pode ser uma oportunidade para fazer outra pergunta. Quando a pergunta não é bem o que foi perguntado, eu particularmente, costumo avisar isto para que fique claro, mas não negativar.

Jamais devemos negativar uma resposta porque tem outra melhor, mesmo que esta tenha mais votos que a melhor. Votar assim é um compensação, é péssimo.

Não gostou da solução? Discorda da resposta? Não gosta da forma apresentada Não gosta da técnica ou tecnologia utilizada? De quem respondeu? Segure o negativo, isto não é motivo. Negativar por achou que devia não é motivo.

Muitas vezes um comentário mostrando o problema costuma funcionar melhor. Dê a chance para a pessoa consertar o problema. Se não consertar, o comentário já pode ter serventia para mostrar o problema. Outras vezes o comentário pode ajudar mais. Lembre-se que estamos tentando achar soluções e não problemas. Queremos melhorar o conteúdo do site.

O negativo pode melhorar o conteúdo do site? Se ele for muito ruim, sim. Não deixe de dar. Mas se pergunte se o conteúdo realmente é ruim, se não pode ser salvo. Não se pergunte como a pessoa vai se sentir. Isto não é motivo para deixar de votar. É o conteúdo!

## Votos no Meta

Aqui é diferente. Os votos tendem a ser mais por concordância e discordância sobre o que foi postado. Ele é um termômetro do que a comunidade pensa. Na pergunta nem sempre é assim. Muitas vezes o voto é dado pela relevância do assunto para a comunidade.

Particularmente não gosto de votar em coisas efêmeras, principalmente *bugs* e suporte muito específico, isto não vai ajudar ninguém depois de resolvido. Normalmente 1 ou 2 votos pra mim já é suficiente neste tipo de postagem.

Lembrando que aqui não se ganha ou perde pontos de reputação por dar ou receber votos.

## Conclusão

Democracia é as pessoas votarem por suas consciências. Podemos listar aqui os motivos que são bons para negativar, mas o julgamento de cada um vai prevalecer.

Os positivos muitas vezes causa mais estrago que os negativos. Esses dias achei uma resposta com mais de 20 votos e aceitação e estava completamente errada. A certa tinhas uns 3 ou 4 votos. A democracia não é perfeita.

A quase totalidade dos meus negativos são em perguntas e a maioria é dada depois de um tempo. Hoje negativo menos porque tem mais pessoas negativando coisas ruins. Teve um tempo que eu fazia isto quase sozinho. A comunidade está melhorando. Mas não pode parar de evoluir. Ainda precisa tomar mais cuidado tanto com negativos, quanto com positivos.

Comment: Excelente resposta bigown.

Answer (score 4):

> **Quando devo realizar um downvote?**

Não concordo com as partes de "sem esforço de pesquisa" e a parte de "baixa qualidade" (para perguntas).

Já foi descutido [nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4432/20615) a questão de perguntas sem pesquisas prévias, não cabe entrar em detalhes aqui. Mas apenas contextualizando:

> O Google é um repositório de informações, ele não "responde nada", apenas nos leva para sites que respondem. Porque esse site não poderia ser o SOpt?

Sobre perguntas de baixa qualidade, eu não acho que merece levar um **downvote** de início. Muitas vezes são novatos que não sabem das regras, e merecem uma tentativa de ajuda antes. Após essa tentativa sim, eu concordo com o **downvote**.

> **Quando realizar um downvote?**

Não concordo com nenhum dos pontos levantados, irei comentar um por um abaixo.

> **Pergunta pobre e/ou má escrita, realizar votedown. (vale usar o bom senso e tentar editar a pergunta para ela ficar mais clara e/ou melhor escrita, caso não seja possível realizar o downvote)**

Muitas vezes uma pergunta pode parecer pobre, mais isso pode ser mudado com um simples comentário. Se votar negativo rápido, sem menos tentar ajudar, a pergunta pode ser fechada sem o AP conseguir editar a mesma. Claro, a mesma pode ser reaberta depois de fechada, etc, etc, etc. Porém, a mensagem que passa para o AP (que muitas vezes é novato ou ainda não possui uma opinião formada sobre o SOpt) é que a comunidade não aceita esses tipos de pergunta.

> **Código colado sem ajuda para interpretação, um grande volume de código que não é necessário para a pergunta em si, falta de compromisso em ajudar que quer ler a pergunta a entender facilmente. (downvote)**

Nesse caso eu concordo, discordando com você. 
Muitas vezes os membros do SOpt são olhados como "Deuses", que sabem tudo apenas olhando o erro. É um bom senso nosso pedir mais informações sobre o mesmo. Até porque quem está precisando de ajuda muitas vezes não sabe o que está buscando. Não digo que não merece **downvote**, apenas que use com moderação e cautela.

> **Pergunta fora dos padrões da comunidade (downvote)**

Não acho que esse tipo de perguntas merece **downvote**, e sim que seja sinalizada para ser fechada. Afinal, temos essa excelente funcionalidade, então vamos usá-lá.

Um exemplo é [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105113/20615). Neste momento ela está com **-6**, mas ninguém sinalizou a mesma para fechar. O que é melhor para a comunidade, ter uma pergunta dessas com tantos negativos ou ter a mesma fechada e sem negativos?

> **Não leu a documentação da linguagem (downvote)**

Essa é a que menos concordo. Muitas, mas muitas documentações não são fácies de ser compreendida, sem falar dos inúmeros erros que possuem. Um exemplo disso é a documentação do [PHP em Portugês](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/index.php). Quantas vezes já li, aqui mesmo no SOpt, bons profissionais reclamando dessa documentação. Assim como essa existe diversas com o mesmo padrão.

> **Aí você pode perguntar: "Pelo que você falou então, o downvote não serve para nada? Está apenas de enfeite?**

Não é bem assim. Algumas de suas opiniões estão corretas, mas acho que devemos ter mais cautela em questão de perguntas. Muitas vezes as perguntas podem ser editadas e melhoradas sem **downvote**, apenas com um simples comentário você pode fazer a diferença.

Já com respostas não. Para responder a pessoa deve saber do que está falando. O intuito de uma resposta e resolver um problema, e não causar mais. Nesses casos eu sou a favor do **downvote**.

- Muitas vezes vemos respostas sem referências (quando são copiadas do SOen).
- Respostas baseadas em opinião (apesar da opinião estar certa, e a forma correta, em alguns casos (especialmente respostas teóricas) ter referência para nos assegurar é o indicado).
- Respostas que não é de fácil compreensão. Não por falta de conhecimento, e sim porque o AR não soube se expressar, deixando o AP mais confuso do que quando abriu a pergunta.

Porém, sempre prefiro comentar e tentar ajudar ao dar um **downvote**.