# Eu não sei perguntar, e você?

Tags: debate, perguntas, comportamento, comunidade

Às vezes quero fazer uma pergunta no site e tudo dá errado.

Quando eu consigo definir o problema de forma concisa e objetiva, eu acabo facilmente encontrando a resposta em algum outro lugar.

Outras vezes eu não consigo explicar direito o que eu preciso, outras eu acho que consigo, mas mesmo assim parece que todo mundo entende outra coisa.

Um dia fiz uma pergunta que achava muito interessante e pertinente e ela foi fechada rapidamente sem chance de resposta e eu não sabia o que fazer para satisfazer os diversos comentários de que eu "devia melhorar" (melhorar o quê?) ou "acrescentar mais informações" (colocar o quê, exatamente?).

Noutra ocasião tentei responder a uma pergunta que achei simples e logo recebi alguns negativos. Fiquei sem entender o porquê até que alguém comentou que eu precisava explicar melhor a minha solução. Bem, eu fiz isso, mas os votos negativos continuaram lá. Nesses casos, poucas vezes os votos negativos são revertidos e pode acontecer até de mais negativos chegarem mesmo depois da melhoria.

E você? Quais foram suas experiências ruins no site com votos negativos, fechamentos e outras situações que lhe deixaram desconfortável ou até resolvido?

---

<sub>Nota: este é um post de desabafo. Talvez alguns relatos de experiências negativas possam ajudar quem vier a passar por isso no futuro e também a ajudar a quem ler modificar um pouco o comportamento em ocasiões oportunas.</sub>

<sub>**Nota 2: como disse acima, este é um post de desabafo. A ideia é ter um lugar para as pessoas descarregarem suas emoções e para o qual possamos direcioná-las quando elas também estiverem sofrendo com isso. Infelizmente, algumas pessoas trouxeram um debate existente que eu não desejava, mas ainda assim acredito que o objetivo foi alcançado e a resposta do Luiz Vieira, por exemplo, tem um conteúdo canônico sobre a questão que pode vir a ajudar muita gente. **</sub>

Comment: Realmente elaborar uma boa pergunta é complicado. Minhas perguntas foram melhores quando não tinha um problema pra resolver, e sim uma dúvida apenas. É dificil expressar um problema em texto as vezes, até porque muitas vezes mal compreendemos o problema, imagina detalha-lo.

Comment: Sugestão de título fictício: `Faço respostas fantásticas mas na hora de perguntar dá errado? Será que aquele guia do Jon SKeet é bom mesmo?`

Comment: Excelente iniciativa, parabéns!

Comment: Parece que alguém andou a testar a sua teoria :P
[Comoo arrastar uma div na minha página?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111415/arrastar-uma-div-na-minha-pagina)

Comment: *"Quando eu consigo definir o problema de forma concisa e objetiva, eu acabo facilmente encontrando a resposta em algum outro lugar."* - isso acontece-me também a toda a hora :)

Comment: E isso é um problema mesmo (acabar encontrando a resposta enquanto faz a pergunta), pq as pessoas não gostam nem um pouco (embora seja estimulado pelo site) que vc poste uma pergunta para a qual vc já sabe a resposta (o @Wallace Maxters que o diga :P). E elas costumam ser más, e te enchem de -1, e acabam com a sua auto estima, e destroem o seu dia... Não seja como estas pessoas.

Comment: Eu considero que eu sei perguntar... mas isso não significa que um dia ou outro eu faça uma pergunta MaisOuMenos|Ruim|QueNinguémEntende|Duplicada|ForaDoEscopo|etc... Eu tento não levar para o lado pessoal.
**Esclarecimento**:Não quer dizer que seja o seu caso...

Comment: @Sergio Lembro de ter lido uma vez que quando você "pensa em como fazer uma boa pergunta, então você entende realmente seu problema e, a partir daí, fica fácil resolver". Não me lembro onde foi.

Comment: [Aprende aí.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111689/%C3%89-correto-nomear-atributos-de-tags-html-de-maneira-arbitr%C3%A1ria) :D

Comment: A pergunta [Como arrastar uma div na minha página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111415/como-arrastar-uma-div-na-minha-p%C3%A1gina) certamente foi feita para ganhar a medalha pressão dos amigos ou similar

Comment: Hoje percebo que não sei perguntar e nem responder, vejo muito usuário com pergunta vaga, já logo ganha +1, +2, +3 e muitas respostas ganharem +10, +20. Eu pergunto vai pro limbo, no máximo +2... Eu respondo e dificilmente passa do +2, no ultimo dia só recebi upvote do AP. Agora eu vejo um cara postou uma resposta simples em menos de 5 min ganhou +3... Eu não vou ser hipócrita, gosto de ganhar votos, mas pra mim sempre parece mais dificil, não consigo saber aonde melhorar :/

Comment: Votei down, e quero manifestar uma alegria em fazer isso, porque você sabe fazer sim perguntas boas, prova disso o saldo positivo desta pergunta, então voto é contra seu sentimento de baixa estima;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, eu queria comentar que eu entendi que estas são postagens de desabafo. Certo? Sendo assim, me entristece notar como *aqui também* há muito *julgamento*. No meu entendimento, desabafo era pra ser só isso mesmo: desabafo. Você não precisa concordar nem discordar, apenas respeitar e no máximo (se você realmente se preocupar com o meu bem-estar) mandar um "*there, there*" e me oferecer uma bebida quente. :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### A Questão Sistêmica

Essas coisas acontecem mesmo. E na minha opinião, são (infelizmente) inevitáveis. Fazem parte da natureza humana. De fato, e eu creio que eu já mencionei isso antes por aqui no Meta ou no chat, todo o funcionamento do sistema da SE se baseia no complexo comportamento coletivo de colônias de animais (mais comumente de insetos, mas que funciona pra outros animais também), chamado [estigmergia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigmergy).

Numa colônia de formigas, por exemplo, funciona assim:

> Ao procurar comida no ambiente, inicialmente de forma totalmente
>   arbitrária, uma única formiga eventualmente encontra uma fonte de
>   alimento (olha, um enorme doce caído no chão!). Como ela sabe onde
>   fica o formigueiro, ela volta pra ele carregando um pedaço pequeno
>   daquele doce (que é o que ela consegue carregar sozinha). Mas ela
>   marca o caminho deixando no ambiente um rastro de feromônio (um
>   marcador químico), de forma que ela mesma possa seguir esse caminho
>   novamente pra voltar depois e pegar mais um pedacinho, e depois mais
>   um pedacinho, e assim sucessivamente. Só que, enquanto isso na sala de
>   justiça, outra formiga - que também estava buscando comida
>   arbitrariamente - se depara com aquele traçado de feromônio que, veja
>   que coincidência, é exatamente o mesmo da colônia dela!
>
> Essa outra formiga então, que também sabe onde fica o formigueiro,
>   segue o caminho na direção oposta e encontra a fonte de alimento.
>   Passa a carregar também um pedacinho (o máximo que ela consegue
>   carregar), e *reforça* o caminho com feromônio dela (o mesmo, já que
>   todas as formigas no formigueiro compartilham o mesmo marcador
>   químico). E outra formiga se junta ao traçado, e mais outra, e
>   eventualmente tem-se um grande número de trabalhadoras levando
>   alimento para o formigueiro. Isso continua assim até que o alimento
>   acabe e as formigas precisem voltar a procurar por mais alimento por
>   ai, novamente de forma arbitrária. Eventualmente elas irão seguir o
>   rastro novamente, apenas para chegar à "fonte" e descobrir que ela
>   acabou. Mas o feromônio é um líquido, de forma que se não for
>   reforçado ele simplesmente evapora. E por isso um caminho que é
>   construído sem uma coordenação e de forma totalmente dinâmica, também
>   é dinamicamente eliminado.

Toda essa historinha serve pra ilustrar o fato de que o comportamento humano também é bastante estigmérgico. No Facebook, por exemplo, certos tipos de conteúdos começam a ser compartilhados e quanto mais isso ocorre mais pessoas tendem a compartilhá-lo (mesmo que seja uma grande bobagem ou uma inverdade que pode fazer mal a alguém). Não é a toa que esse tipo de conteúdo é vulgarmente chamado de "viral". `pausa pra pensar a respeito`

No caso dos sistemas da SE, é justamente esse mecanismo que faz com que o conteúdo seja mais facilmente filtrado. Perguntas e respostas boas ou ruins vão receber votos, e é *totalmente natural* que quanto mais votos tenham, mais votos elas atraiam.

**Do ponto de vista sistêmico** isso é bom, porque ajuda a separar o conteúdo de qualidade do conteúdo sem qualidade: perguntas/respostas melhores tendem a atrair muita atenção, aparecer primeiro nas consultas, etc, enquanto que perguntas/respostas ruins tendem a demandar correção, uma vez que o autor passa a temer grandes perdas de reputação e a postagem em si passa a atrair a atenção da comunidade (não é - ou não deveria ser - normal ter uma postagem com `-20` votos).

> De fato, recentemente teve uma discussão sobre a medalha
>   *peer-pressure* (que eu não participei), mas - na minha opinião - essa medalha é apenas um prêmio de consolação para um fato natural da
>   auto-organização estigmérgica desse tipo de sistema.

**Do ponto de vista social**, isso não é necessariamente tão bom. Se por um lado os indivíduos têm menos trabalho no sentido de que não é necessário ter muito esforço de gestão, por outro lado injustiças tendem a ser levianamente reforçadas. Note que injustiças podem ser tanto um conteúdo bom que levou votos negativos injustamente, como um conteúdo ruim que levou votos positivos injustamente. E isso ocorre apenas porque aquele número de votos é uma informação que ganha relevância imediata muito maior do que o conteúdo da postagem (é um feromônio que infesta nossos sentidos e que nos faz votar e seguir involuntariamente o nosso rebanho).

**Mas, ainda assim, por mais que isso seja uma injustiça, ela ocorre em pequena quantidade dentro de cada postagem.** Por que? Porque o próprio sistema ajuda nesse sentido. Uma grande injustiça (uma boa postagem com `-20`, por exemplo) salta mais facilmente aos sentidos (aos olhos, no nosso caso, já que não usamos feromônios aqui de verdade), e faz com que certos mecanismos de proteção se ativem rapidamente (vide, postagens no Meta, reclamações em comentários, argumentos no chat, etc). Qualquer um de nós, como autor de conteúdo, temos a tendência de reclamar mais ao receber 5 ou 10 votos negativos do que ao receber 1 ou 2. E essa tendência escala apropriadamente (1 ou 2 votos, eu posto um comentário perguntando o porquê, 5 votos dai já é demais, e eu abro uma postagem no Meta).

Então a minha conclusão é que o sistema funciona. Ele não é perfeito, claro, mas ele funciona. Pelo menos no sentido do que se almeja: classificar o conteúdo como bom/ruim de acordo com uma escala *flexivel* de reputação (não é só você, autor, que tem reputação; o conteúdo também e se chama votos).

Tudo isso que eu falei, vale também para outras atuações sistêmicas. Os votos para fechar, por exemplo, também sofrem todas esses efeitos. A partir do momento em que uma pergunta recebe um voto para fechar, ela tende a receber mais votos e isso é natural. O voto, como mecanismo de feedback sensorial, atrai muito mais atenção para aquele conteúdo. E, novamente, injustiças acontecem, mas elas tendem a ser pequenas. Grandes injustiças facilmente motivam discussões. Mesmo que ela seja considerada uma grande injustiça pelos olhos de apenas um membro da comunidade.

### A Questão da Experiência de Usuário

Bom, o sistema funciona, mas isso não quer dizer que nós não possamos tentar melhorá-lo. Do ponto de vista da experiência dos usuários, é péssimo se sentir injustiçado. O problema maior é que pequenas injustiças, acumuladas, não prejudicam tanto a qualidade do conteúdo como prejudicam a vontade dos membros da comunidade em participar (ou continuar participando).

Sim, eu também acho que cada um de nós deveríamos ser menos apressados em votar, tomar cuidado com injustiças, conversar mais calmamente, ouvir mais o que os colegas têm a dizer, etc, etc, etc. Mas esse é um problema que ocorre em tantos outros escopos, maiores do que esse inclusive, que está simplesmente além do nosso controle (bom, eu consigo tentar melhorar a mim mesmo, mas não tenho muita influência no comportamento do meu coleguinha).

Sendo assim, há algumas coisas que eu acho que poderiam ser alteradas do ponto de vista sistêmico pra tentar conduzir o comportamento individual para que o comportamento coletivo seja melhor. Explico-as:

- **[Votos negativos deveriam ter custo mais alto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/73)**. Votar é importante pelos argumentos que eu já descrevi anteriormente. Faz parte do mecanismo estigmérgico que o sistema usa. E, muito embora os votos positivos e negativos tenham a mesma importância sistêmica e social, os votos negativos são aqueles que prejudicam mais facilmente a experiência dos participantes com a comunidade e com o sistema. O voto negativo já tem hoje um custo, mas eu creio que ele é muito pequeno. As pessoas **não precisam** votar negativamente para ajudar o sistema a funcionar, pois a ausência de votos positivos têm um efeito similar. Perguntas com mais votos positivos também se destacam de perguntas que têm pouco ou não têm voto algum. Assim, se o voto negativo custasse mais, as pequenas injustiças - mais danosas à experiência - poderiam ser evitadas *por mais tempo*. Note que isso não resolveria completamente o problema, pois alguém com muita reputação e má intenção ainda poderia pagar o custo apenas pra votar "injustamente" se assim desejasse. Mas reduziria o comportamento meramente estigmático (voto sem pensar muito, apenas porque tá "aparentemente" ruim), porque conectaria o voto a um processo mais racional relacionado à perda significativa de algo como a reputação.
- **[Critérios de fechamento deveriam ser explícitos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4858/73)**. Outra questão importante do ponto de vista da experiência é que as injustiças não são facilmente perceptíveis. No caso dos votos não há mesmo justificativa (e nem deveria - essa é outra discussão), mas nos fechamentos há justificativas que são simplesmente escondidas. Parece-me terrivelmente ruim o fato de que não importa a justificativa que eu escolhi para votar no fechamento de uma pergunta, a que aparece para o usuário é aquela que teve mais votos. Já houve casos em que uma pergunta deveria ser fechada (na minha opinião) como não clara, e muitas outras pessoas votaram nela como fora do escopo. Bom, se em 5 votos apenas o meu foi diferente, talvez eu esteja errado. Mas, e se 3 pessoas votaram em coisas totalmente distintas e outros 2 votaram no mesmo item, faz mesmo sentido a pergunta ser fechada indicando esse item (que os 2 votaram) como a razão? O fato de não haver concordância no motivo do fechamento *deveria* ser um indicativo de que há problemas maiores nessa pergunta. Assim, mesmo que para o autor da postagem aparecesse apenas o motivo com mais votos, deveria ser possível *a todos* consultar a qualquer momento quais foram os motivos individuais de sugestão de fechamento. Talvez fosse interessante também que questões fechadas sem uma concordância razoável fossem enviadas para uma fila de análise ou que necessitassem de mais votos.
- **[O voto para fechar não deveria ser enviesado apenas para o lado negativo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4859/73)**. Muitas vezes a comunidade vota para fechar uma pergunta que eu acho que tem salvação, mas eu não tenho como questionar até que a pergunta seja fechada e eu vote para reabrir. Alternativamente eu posso abrir uma questão no meta, mas há de se perceber que o Meta é um tanto exclusivo (não são todos os membros que participam). O fato é que uma vez que uma pergunta é votada para fechar, ela tem ali um marcador (uma setinha de votos) similar ao da votação normal, mas apenas pra baixo. A estigmergia funciona, atraindo novos votantes, **mas ninguém é capaz de votar em oposição**. Talvez fosse interessante exibir uma opção para votar como "manter aberta", opção essa que seria exibida a partir do momento em que a primeira pessoa votasse para fechar. Uma pergunta que tivesse menos votos para fechar do que para manter aberta certamente não deveria ser fechada (sem qualquer discussão necessária). Isso pode ser bom ou ruim, claro, dependendo do uso que as pessoas fazem. Mas, certamente parece mais justo ao autor do conteúdo envolvido.

### Concluindo

Acho que viajei demais nas minhas colocações, mas elas foram só isso mesmo: colocações. Ninguém precisa concordar ou discordar. Nem sei se respondi à sua pergunta corretamente, mas acho que ai no meio tem de certa forma as coisas que me incomodam geralmente.

E é isso ai.

:wq

Comment: Propostas interessantes. Por que não as coloca individualmente para poderem ser melhor discutidas?

Comment: @ramaral Obrigado. Mas acho melhor esperar um pouco mais pra vermos se há mais feedback nesse sentido nesta resposta mesmo. :)

Comment: Que sacanagem, hein? Já não basta fazer os melhores *posts* no principal, agora vem fazer isso aqui no meta? :) Ainda que eu não concorde com tudo, está perfeito. Estas ideias já existem no MSE há tempos, e nem vou falar mais nada... :)

Comment: Desculpa ai, @bigown. Foi sem querer querendo. :)

Comment: Não vi viagem nenhuma, gostei da análise! Boas sugestões no final também. Eu não tenho certeza sobre a primeira sugestão, mas concordo com as outras duas – e tem outros dados ocultos no site, como os das filas de análise (onde, aliás, existem os votos de "manter aberta").

Comment: Muito bom mesmo. +1 E lendo a sua primeira sugestão me ocorreu aqui se não seria interessante possibilitar o voto negativo **apenas quando já tiver um positivo** ou então que a pergunta/resposta ficasse com apenas -1 ou -2 votos negativos. Porque isso já resolveria a classificação de conteúdo (com -1 ou -10 já se sabe que o conteúdo é ruim e pronto, mas o contrário **não** é verdade, +10 é uma excelente resposta, +1 é maaais ou meeenos :)), e evitaria o -10 que as vezes ocorre e acaba com a participação de alguns usuários...

Comment: Excelente post! Particularmente, gostei das 3 sugestões e acho que cada uma delas mereceria sim um post próprio, pra tentar aprimorar a ideia até algo que possa ser sugerido como parte do sistema. É um problema do nosso Meta, por conta da língua, que é mais difícil tentar discutir alterações profundas na plataforma. Isso não é ideal e não sabemos muito bem como resolver. Mas ainda acho que qualquer uma das 3 ideias merece uma discussão maior em torno delas.

Comment: @ramaral Ok, fiz como você originalmente sugeriu e abri postagens individuais sobre as minhas sugestões. Obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: Ok @Gabe, eu abri as postagens separadamente.

Comment: @gustavox Não sei se limitar a liberdade de voto é um bom caminho. Minha sugestão era tornar o voto negativo mais significativo por meio do custo, mas não de impedir seu uso.

Comment: @LuizVieira Ótimo! Vou dar uma olhada. Pena que no meio do carnaval é difícil que muita gente vá estar disponível pra debater :D

Comment: Mas tornar mais caro também é uma forma de limitar o uso... A questão é: para que serve o voto negativo? Pra classificar o conteúdo. E com -1 ou -2 já está classificado. Pensar num direito absoluto ao voto negativo como uma prerrogativa do usuário não me parece muito correto. O voto negativo tem apenas este lado positivo (classificar o conteúdo), em tudo mais ele é ruim. Qual a utilidade de um negativo a mais numa pergunta/resposta com -5? Nenhuma. E na minha opinião, mesmo com -2. Pra que serve o -3? Pra nada. Só serve pra perder usuários, desanimar as pessoas de interagir por aqui...

Comment: @gustavox Bom, ainda assim é uma expressão de opinião de um usuário. Esse cara que deu mais um -1 está também reforçando uma visão com a opinião pessoal (que pode ser só mais um voto em uma quantidade enorme de votos positivos e/ou negativos). Eu tendo a acreditar que dar opções significativas é melhor para a experiência do que simplesmente não dar opções.

Comment: Então, o que eu penso em evitar é a desnecessária humilhação do usuário, com uma quantidade desnecessária de negativos. Talvez se ao invés de limitar os negativos, poderia ter algo ao invés de pontos, e os votos iriam sendo computados, e quando ficasse negativo, apareceria que aquela pergunta/resposta estava negativada, e quando os votos ficassem com saldo positivo, isso deixaria de aparecer... e só usuários com X rep poderiam ver quanto está a votação... deu pra entender? PS: mas com os positivos não, estes sempre teriam a contagem aparecendo...

Comment: E só pra constar, eu sou favorável a aumentar o custo, inclusive já votei no tópico específico. O que to falando aqui é só uma ideia paralela que surgiu enquanto lia sua resposta...

Comment: @gustavox Entendi. Bom, por que não abre uma nova postagem com essa ideia paralela? :)

Comment: É, outro dia talvez eu abra, depois de amadurecer um pouco a ideia...

Answer (score 9):

Não irei fazer nada muito longo, até porque o @bigown já escreveu muitos pontos em sua resposta, e que concordo. Mas deixarei minha opinião sobre o que está acontecendo por aqui.

Não é de hoje que estamos com esse "problema" de votos e fechamentos indevidos. O critério usado por cada pessoa está cada vez mais difícil de se entender. No gráfico abaixo podemos ver por exemplo o aumento de downvotes que o site teve.

<kbd>[image: Média dos votos negativos]</kbd>

<sup>Fonte: [O que está acontecendo com os votos negativos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4803/20615)</sup>

Mas isso não está ocorrendo somente com o downvote. Fechamentos, edições e outras funcionalidades do site não estão sendo analisadas como deveriam.

Podemos ver que a questão de "opinião" causa várias dúvidas no site, [esta pergunta exemplifica muito bem isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4801/20615). Nela possui pessoas a favor e contra a abertura de uma pergunta. Se todos tivessem o mesmo pensamento de "como usar o site" essa pergunta não iria existir.

Outra questão apresentada são os votos. Temos [essa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4701/20615) sobre o assunto. Não teve tanta visibilidade quanto poderia, mas na discussão sobre ela vimos que cada um pensa diferente sobre isso.

[Na sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111415/20615) podemos ver que foi fechada e teve votos negativos. Eu particularmente acho isso redundante e que pode assustar novos usuários, mas isso é assunto para [esta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4818/20615), e frustrar usuários antigos.

**Mas, sabe o que mais me assustou com a "pergunta exemplo"?**
Apesar de várias pessoas falarem para não votarem ou fazer nenhuma outra ação por causa da pessoa, neste caso o utluiz, ninguém que votou para fechar, ou negativou tentou ajudar a melhorar a pergunta. Se não é para para fazer nenhuma ação por causa da pessoa e tratar todos iguais, porque não tratar **TODOS IGUAIS?**

Pontuação e/ou "fama" aqui no site não significa que a pessoa pode ter dúvidas e/ou dificuldades para elaborar seus pensamentos.

**Respondendo a pergunta**

Esse trecho de sua pergunta eu achei muito interessante. Ele exemplifica bem o que temos como "principal dificuldade" a abrir uma pergunta:

> Um dia fiz uma pergunta que achava muito interessante e pertinente e ela foi fechada rapidamente sem chance de resposta e eu não sabia o que fazer para satisfazer os diversos comentários de que eu "devia melhorar" (melhorar o que?) ou "acrescentar mais informações" (colocar o quê, exatamente?).

Por um lado, pode ser difícil se expressar para quem está perguntando, mas por outro, pode ser difícil para quem está respondendo também. Muitas vezes não entendemos o que está sendo pedido na pergunta, e com isso, não temos como saber "o que pedir para melhorar". Claro muitas vezes também não "damos" a mínima e apenas votamos, e isso que está errado.

Como disse o [@DenerCarvalho em sua resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4831/20615), o melhor a fazer é **ter paciência e tentar se colocar no lugar do AP**. Ter conhecimento não é algo que ajude a se expressar, muitas vezes acontece o contrário. Às vezes um "simples comentário" pode ajudar a melhorar a pergunta, o que falta as vezes é esse "simples comentário".

Comment: "As vezes um "simples comentário" pode ajudar a melhorar a pergunta, o que falta as vezes é esse "simples comentário". É mesmo...

Comment: Note que o aumento de dezembro pra cá é generalizado na rede e acho que cabe uma análise e uma explicação por parte da SE. O aumento ocorrido durante o ano eu acho que porque as pessoas cansaram. O aumento iniciou quando quando eu estava ausente do site :) Me desculpe se parece presunçoso, mas eu acho que eu conseguia colocar as coisas em melhor perspectiva. Certos discursos só radicalizam as ações. É o que eu chamo de tiro que sai pela culatra. As pessoas não vão mudar o comportamento por causa desses discursos. Elas querem um site com melhor conteúdo. Concordo com a resposta.

Comment: Só discordo que não foi tentado melhorar a pergunta. Até ignoraram que era o utluiz. E como ele não fez nada para arrumar tomou o negativo. Claro que ele esperava isso. Claro que ele não iriam arrumar. Tem 2 comentários lá. Precisa mais p/ um usuário que nem é novato? Mesmo que precise, queremos ter o fardo de ficar fazendo tudo para salvar algo ruim? É nossa obrigação tentar salvar tudo? Hoje eu negativo bem menos do que negativava antes. E meus negativos costumam ser depois que a pessoa teve a chance de arrumar. Em geral prefiro fechar que negativar.

Comment: @bigown Não posso afirmar se as pessoas se cansaram ou não. Deveria ocorrer um estudo para determinar isso, até porque se você olhar no meta a quantidade de perguntas sobre o mesmo assunto verá que possuem diversos fatores. Mas eu adicionei a parte dos votos apenas para exemplificar melhor o que todos falaram aqui, votos!

Comment: @bigown A parte do comentário ocorreu antes mesmo da pergunta no meta que ele abriu. E mesmo se fosse, não está ocorrendo apenas com essa pergunta, basta ver as fechadas que verá que muitas nem comentários possuem.

Comment: @Randrade com certeza tem coisas que podem ter uma ação melhor, no caso desta pergunta-teste, acho que tudo funcionou direitinho, exceto pelo positivos dados nela :D

Comment: @bigown Neste ponto eu tenho que concordar com você.

Comment: Acho que ela poderia ter sido fechada antes e o Guilherme ter respondido na duplicata. Esse é mais um furo do mecanismo. Nem vou me aprofundar nisto.

Answer (score 8):

Eu não sei perguntar. Na verdade, acho que iniciante algum sabe, ou entra sem saber.

Confesso, e acredito que assim como outros, comecei de forma errada. Sem ler as regras de como tudo funciona.

Sou iniciante em programaçao e isso piora mais ainda minha situaçao, pois minhas perguntas sempre parecem bobas, facéis de mais para se tomar tempo aqui, com tantas outras perguntas difíceis.

Só tenho que agradecer aos que tiveram paciência em ajudar e agradeço por este post, este espaço para desabafar.

Comment: Joás, gostei bastante da sua resposta. Quer saber de uma coisa? Nós precisamos de mais perguntas bobas e fáceis de iniciantes. Claro que seria ideal que elas fossem bem elaboradas, no sentido de serem bem escritas e formatadas e tivessem um objetivo claro. Essas perguntas são as mais gostosas de responder e possibilitam pessoas com menos experiência participarem mais, enquanto perguntas difíceis tomam tempo e só vão chamar a atenção de poucos.

Comment: Tambem sinto isso @utluiz sobre perguntas faceis, e tudo mais. Até tenho procurado responder aquelas que parecem ter ficado pra traz, sem respostas. Mas ainda persiste este problema com pessoas, como eu, que chegam de "bolo", sem conhecer a proposta do site, sem organizaçao. Inclusive, acho que muito que chegaram aqui foi porque já vinham atrelados a algum questionamente, ansiedade em resolver algum problema na area. E terminam ficando perdidos, pois querem continuar aqui, mas nao começaram do jeito certo. A prova disso deve ser a quantidade de perfis abandonados, com menos de 50 ou 100 pontos

Answer (score 7):

Eu não sabia, mas aprendi. E agora que sei, quase nunca preciso, porque em geral acho a resposta enquanto cumpro a liturgia de fazer uma boa pergunta:

1 - Pesquise direito, não basta só uma jogada no google;

2 - Pense bem sobre tudo o que pesquisou;

3 - Pesquise de novo;

4 - Veja se ninguém perguntou isso antes;

5 - Limite a pergunta àquilo que é realmente necessário.

6 - Procure eventuais erros de digitação no código que possam estar ocasionando o problema (não te perdoarão por isso! :P);

7 - Procure de novo;

8 - Mostre o que você tentou;

9 - Se for um problema específico, crie um snippet (e se quer ser um ninja das perguntas, então crie um fiddle TAMBÉM);

10 - Revise a pergunta.

11 - Revise de novo.

E depois cruze os dedos, porque sabe como é, muitos vão ajudar, mas *haters gonna*...

Comment: Realmente gustavox, os *haters gonna hate* rsrs +1

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

Minha primeira pergunta que fiz aqui no SOpt foi sobre recomendações de plataformas e-commerce gratuitas ou open source. Depois que fiz minha pergunta, eu recebi alguns negativos e em seguida ela foi fechada por se baseada em opiniões. Entretanto, recebi um comentário com um link com uma lista de plataformas e-commerce gratuitas e algumas open source, e demorou para mim voltar a acessar o SOpt depois da pergunta que fiz. Mas, com o tempo eu percebi o potencial do SOpt e resolvi ser mais ativo.

O problema da minha pergunta que descrevi acima é que não havia um problema, era só uma dúvida qualquer, e eu entendi perfeitamente o motivo do fechamento e achei correto, depois de um tempo de reflexão.

*Contudo, sera que a maioria dos iniciantes em programação e novos usuários aceitariam ter sua primeira pergunta negativada e fechada ou marcada como pedente com umas dessas legendas:*

> Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para
>   destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é
>   difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a
>   página Como perguntar para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta
>   pergunta.

*Por ela não ser bem formulada ou carecer objetivo e informações?* **Acho que vários votos negativos é pior do que fechar as vezes.**

Talvez não exista uma resposta para a pergunta acima ou exista milhares de respostas, irá depender do ponto de vista do leitor.

Eventualmente, passa pela mente dos novos usuários que os votos negativos é uma punição por ele não ter elaborado uma boa pergunta. Quem irá garantir que um usuário recém-chegado não terá nenhum sentimento ruim após ver sua pergunta recebendo vários negativos?

Eu levo tempo para elaborar minhas perguntas aqui no SOpt, devido a algumas limitações que eu possuo, não vem ao caso entrar em detalhes sobre, mas eu procuro sempre descrever o máximo de informação que tem no meu problema. E o problema é que quando eu começo a elaborar a pergunta com as informações que tenho, acaba surgindo uma solução devido as informações, interessante, e as vezes deixo de perguntar. Contudo, quando vou fazer uma pergunta em que eu *não tenho domínio do problema* ou *conhecimento do assunto*, eu me perco na elaboração da mesma. Às vezes o problema é *muito grande* ou a *fonte dele esta muito oculta*, assim a pergunta corre o risco de sair mal formulada, sem objetivo, sem informação. Como eu conheço o SOpt, opto por não fazer uma pergunta deste tipo, até que consiga um pouco mais de informação a respeito do problema para elaborá-la melhor.

Entretanto, não é todo usuário novo que tem esta mesma atitude que eu quando se depara com um problema muito grande em que falta informação ou lhe falta conhecimento do assunto que envolve o problema, ou simplesmente não consegue explicá-lo ou formulá-lo em uma pergunta, e a pergunta acaba saindo **mal formulada, não clara, difícil de interpretar, difícil de entender, mal escrita, muito ampla, baseada em opiniões, subjetiva**, e acaba caindo numa dessas armadilhas, pra não dizer em todas. Porém, como podemos ajudar este usuário, principalmente os novos e iniciantes na programação, a elaborar uma boa pergunta?

Bom, a minha resposta é paciência e tentar se colocar no lugar do AP, tentar mostrar para ele que ele deve fazer a pergunta como se a dúvida fosse dele e de outras 10.000 (dez mil) pessoas ou mais, que ele deve perguntar representando essas dez mil pessoas, que serão ajudadas, para que a pergunta dele se torne um caminho para várias soluções do problema que ela descreve.

Comment: Não entendi porque o TL;DR lá em cima.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sempre quis usar isso kkkk (leitura longa não leia)

Comment: **TL;DR** https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Muito_longo;_n%C3%A3o_li

Comment: Dener (CC @Zoom) é que normalmente quando se coloca isso, é porque logo a seguir virá um resumo do que tem abaixo para ser lido por aqueles que tem pressa ou não podem ler textos longos demais por algum motivo. Já no seu caso, não há resumo nenhum. A ideia não é "*leitura longa, não leia*" a ideia é "*se você não pode ler porque é longo demais, aqui vai um resuminho curtinho*".

Comment: @VictorStafusa, sim eu sei, pode considerar que o resumo esta la no fim do texto, mais coloquei o TL;DR porque o que esta por vim e um texto longo :), bom eu achei ele longo rsrs

Comment: "A minha resposta é paciência e tentar se colocar no lugar do AP..." A dificuldade é encontrar alguém que esteja disposto de fazer isso kkk Achei que o StackOverflow seria um ótimo lugar para tirar minhas dúvidas de programação, mas os moderadores só parecem um bando de arrogantes que se acham, não explicam nada sobre o porquê de fazermos algo que não os agrada ou o quê, independente dos nossos esforços. Provavelmente vou é desistir dessa comunidade, ficar me matando de pesquisar soluções na internet é melhor do que lidar com um pessoal de nariz empinado que não tem um mínimo senso de empatia

Answer (score -7):

Basicamente, fazemos uma pergunta clara e objetiva, as pessoas que não sabem, votam negativamente, e nunca conseguimos resolver nossos problemas

Comment: Caro Breno, ou então você esta enganado e as perguntas negativas não estão claras e nem objetivas, ou são são OFF. Se tiver clara as pessoas saberão sim responder, mas as pessoas não são adivinhas, ou então se a pergunta esta clara e objetiva e foi fechada é porque é OFF-TOPIC ou porque é "Helpdesk". Nem todo fechamento é pra sempre, a maioria não é, só que temos regras, você precisa seguir se deseja participar, aqui não é helpdesk... já os downvotes geralmente é de pessoas q estão tentando te dar um toque: tem um problema grave na postagem.

Comment: Olá, Breno! Se está ocorrendo isto contigo, você pode perguntar aqui no Meta dos motivos para que o pessoal possa te explicar, mostrando as perguntas que entende que estavam boas mas foram fechadas ou negativadas

Comment: Suas 3 perguntas sobre Laravel tem uma considerável interseção de conteúdo (e as últimas 2 de código também).