# Por que esta resposta foi removida?

Tags: suporte

Porque é que a resposta do bigwon à pergunta: [Eu não sei perguntar, e você?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4829/2541) foi removida?

Foi colocado um comentário em inglês pelo Tim Post.
Aqui é o stackoverflow em português! 
Será possível traduzi-lo para que possa ser completamente bem entendido?

Comment: Eu removi a resposta depois que ele a transformou em um rant de uma única linha.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não consegui perceber completamente o comentário do Tim. É possível traduzi-lo?

Comment: Eu não consegui ver também.

Comment: Tradução do comentário do Tim Post: *Afirmar que só o que é de interesse da SE pode ser dito aqui é falacioso e totalmente inverídico, bem como qualquer outro argumento retórico que parta dessa premissa. Sinto muito, mas você simplesmente está errado quanto a isso.*

Comment: Pra quem não conhece o Tim Post: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0692874/ Fez X Men e tals...

Comment: @Zoom Foi você que negativou a pergunta?

Comment: Foi............

Comment: @Zoom Ok! ......já agora, o que não concorda nela?

Comment: Não acho que precisava ser uma pergunta. E você não apresentou o Tim Post. Eu não o conhecia.

Comment: Então! Você haja que moderador é rei e não deve ser questionado?

Comment: @bfavaretto. Obrigado pela tradução. A razão de ter colocada a pergunta foi por a resposta ter sido fechada imediatamente após o comentário do Tim, no entanto a sua justificação é completamente válida .

Comment: Não, pode questioná-los á vontade.

Comment: @ramaral O fechamento após o comentário foi coincidência. Nem o Tim esperava

Comment: @Gabe Agora vejo como coincidência mas na altura não. Ainda bem que está esclarecido. Se não fosse coincidência algo de muito grave se estava a passar.

Comment: @ramaral Deixarmos um comentário numa resposta logo antes de apagá-la não é uma atitude incomum ou grave. Entendo que, pelas circunstâncias e pelo fato de ser o Tim, pode parecer mais esquisito. Mas não seria nada fora do comum. Claro, desde que o post justifique a remoção, como foi o caso aqui

Comment: @Gabe Julgo que você já entendeu mas para deixar claro. Aquilo que eu vi foi um comentário do **Tim** ao conteúdo original da pergunta e esta foi de imediato eliminada. Perante isso não pude deixar de questionar a razão. Após a explicação do bfavaretto ficou claro a razão do fechamento, a qual eu acho completamente válida.

Comment: Só para situar os leitores, quando removi a resposta eu nem tinha visto que havia um comentário do Tim.

Answer (score 6):

Bem, eu suponho que o bigown tenha ficado de saco cheio com o que estava/está acontecendo e então editou a resposta colocando apenas isso:

> É isso aí, está todo mundo de parabéns. Sugiro daqui um ano fazer uma análise de como o site evoluiu neste quesito.

O que obviamente é uma resposta irônica, mas demonstra que ele está cansado de ficar aqui debatendo a toa para não se chegar a lugar nenhum.

Não sou o bigown, mas conjecturo que o fato do Tim Post ter vindo só para dizer que ele estava errado, um tanto assustador. Eu suponho que ele viu isso como sendo a *gota d'água*, a comprovação de que reclamar sobre as políticas da SE é algo inútil e que tudo isso é uma causa perdida, o que de certa forma, infelizmente apenas acaba afirmando boa parte do que ele queria dizer.

E que fique claro, não concordo com muita coisa do que o bigown disse, mas também já tenho experiência o suficiente para ver que as coisas por aqui estão bem longe de funcionarem da forma como todos gostaríamos e que o sistema Stack Exchange tem vários problemas também. Até porque, o fato de estarmos tendo todos estes debates comprova exatamente o que todos já sabem, que há algo dando errado.

Depois disso, o bfavaretto apagou a resposta. Não estou dizendo que ela não deveria ser apagada, mas também não digo o contrário.

Por fim, eu digo que concordo que há muita coisa dando errado por aqui que precisa ser consertada. Novamente, não concordo com tudo que o bigown disse e discordo dele em vários pontos, mas também concordo em vários outros e não tenho opinião formada em uns tantos outros.

Comment: Eu ia comentar mas vou estar calado que não vale a pena.

Comment: @JorgeB. Peço desculpa mas se não ias concretizar devias ter ficado quieto. Estás a referir-te a quê? À minha pergunta, à resposta do bigown ou a esta resposta?

Comment: @ramaral para bom entendedor ;) Não é para nenhum desses, é para a resposta do Tim.

Comment: Sobre a parte que me toca: era reverter ou apagar. Considerando os estados de ânimo no momento, achei melhor apagar. Não estou dizendo que acertei, mas também não digo o contrário :P

Comment: @bfavaretto Certo, faz sentido. Acho que acabou sendo melhor assim.

Comment: @bfavaretto Qualquer uma dessas opções seria sempre discutível. Havia outra: não fazer nada, pelo menos durante algum tempo.

Comment: O bigown destruiu a própria resposta 10 minutos antes do comentário do Tim. Não teve nada de "gota d'água". Além disso, entendo que é raro ter outro funcionário da SE participar aqui (o que é algo que estamos tentando consertar, inclusive), mas não vejo como pode ser assustador ter outro gerente de comunidades participar do nosso Meta. Além disso, não podemos encarar debates como sinais de que "há algo errado". Uma comunidade que não debate não é uma comunidade que "está dando certo". Muito pelo contrário.

Comment: Ah, e lá vou eu meter o bedelho: não vejo razão pra resposta dele ter sido apagada. Eu cheguei a ver a original (acho) por cima, e vi (acho que uma parte) da discussão com o Zoom, e até tinha favoritado pra ver depois com calma (e pipoca :D) mas a resposta de uma linha que foi apagada já achei exagero, ainda mais que tinha o comentário de uma celeb (os deuses estão loucos hoje por aqui, legal, deixa rolar :D) Até acho que  ele não deveria ter editado  tão drasticamente, tinha coisas interessantes apesar dos pesares...

Comment: Mas não tinha nada grave na resposta editada imho, e pelo menos dava pra ver a anterior no histórico de edição. Acho que deveriam ter sido apagados apenas eventuais comentários desnecessários/desagradáveis. A pergunta mesmo acho que ele ainda poderia reverter para a anterior, ou mesmo editar. Não precisava ter apagado imho.

Comment: @gustavox É uma situação complicada. Da maneira como está, a resposta não serve pra mais nada. Não responde à pergunta, não avança a discussão. É completamente inutil, e perfeitamente dentro das regras apagá-la. A reversão é uma opção que não costuma ser feita em casos de edições do próprio autor. Ele não foi induzido a editar. A decisão foi dele em transformar a resposta em algo completamente inútil.

Comment: É @Gabe, entendo que possa estar nas regras, mas sei lá, o  bigwon é um usuário exemplar, um verdadeiro oráculo aqui do SOpt, então acho que convinha ter tido um pouco mais de confiança de que ele iria resolver isso de alguma forma. Não vejo ele deixando uma resposta de uma linha por muito tempo... Achei precipitado porque eu mesmo quase fiquei sem entender nada. Só entendi o porque de ter sido apagada com este tópico. Pra mim ia ficar a impressão de que ele mesmo tinha apagado a resposta.

Comment: @gustavox De novo, é uma situação complicada. É difícil dar um tratamento diferencial como esse, na esperança de que ele fosse voltar atrás. A resposta nova não tinha nenhum conteúdo aproveitável, era bem combativa e de certa maneira até agressiva. Deixar esse tipo de conteúdo no site, na esperança de que o autor vai voltar atrás não é exatamente a nossa política. De qualquer maneira, ele ainda pode editar a resposta e pedir para ser restaurada. Nenhuma decisão da moderação é completamente irreversível. Basta ele querer.

Comment: Legal @Gabe, é o SOpt sendo o SOpt. Eu confio no sistema, de verdade.  Até tem algumas coisas que não concordo, mas é sem dúvida a melhor moderação que já vi. Tenho certeza de que tudo vai se solucionar da melhor forma, e espero que o bigwon não deixe de colaborar ou colabore menos por isso.

Comment: Aqui se fala tanto em aproveitar ao máximo o que tem de bom nas postagens, em respeitar os usuários etc, mas quando se trata do Bigown, a regra muda e a boa vontade de entender as postagens dele aparenta não existir. Os pesos e medidas mudam. Eu já fiquei bem incomodado com outras coisas que aconteceram na rede em várias situações, já me manifestei em várias delas, e quase todas foram em relação a decisões não comunitárias. Se é para sermos cabeça aberta com todo mundo, nada melhor do que com alguém que defende a existência do site desde a abertura. Ninguém discorda e/ou desabafa à toa.

Comment: @gustavox e demais, só quero deixar claro que foi removido até com minha anuência. Como aparentemente não foi bem recebido, e eu não quero causar problemas, achei melhor retirar aquilo. Mantenho minhas convicções, mas depois de tudo o que ocorreu achei que era melhor deixar sem aquilo. Não vou entrar em detalhes pra não provocar outro debate improdutivo. Quem acompanha tudo o que ocorre e sabe analisar os detalhes dos acontecimentos vai entender que é melhor assim.

Comment: Ninguém é um usuário exemplar, nem o @bigown. Ter quase 100K de reputação não significa que o que ele disser tem abaixar a cabeça ou ser analisado. Ainda mais pelo jeito que foi tratado o assunto. Bacco, isso que você falou não tem fundamento. Eu tenho certeza que o tratamento aqui é imparcial, não importa a pontuação ou o que já foi feito pelo usuário a favor do SOpt. Afirmo isso porquê eu já passei por essa situação. Fui chamado a atenção pelo fato de votar negativamente em série. E o Sérgio me disse que eu deveria pensar melhor nisso e que se isso acontecesse comigo...

Comment: ... eles fariam o que fosse necessário para lutarem por mim. Não tem que passar a mão na cabeça, não tem que querer ficar de um lado ou de outro, tentar achar quem é o culpado e não tem que se fazer de vítima porquê foi intimidado. Apagou a resposta porquê não conseguiu manter a opinião, apagou porquê quem ele queria que desse atenção, não deu. Não deveria ter apagado, não deveria.

Comment: Mas vocês podem dizer: Zoom, acho que você implica demais com o Bigown. É, pode ser. É normal alguém não se dar bem com alguém pela divergência de ideias e personalidade. Porém, achar que o SOpt é melhor ou funciona melhor com as respostas dele é, pra mim, no máximo arrogante. Palavras dele: "O aumento ocorrido durante o ano eu acho que porque as pessoas cansaram. **O aumento iniciou quando quando eu estava ausente do site :) Me desculpe se parece presunçoso, mas eu acho que eu conseguia colocar as coisas em melhor perspectiva.** Certos discursos só radicalizam as ações.". Sério isso ?

Comment: Bom, @Zoom, só pra esclarece a parte que me toca, eu não acompanhei a discussão inteira, e minha opinião se resumiu ao fato de terem apagado a resposta, e não a discussão em si ou aos comentários. De qualquer forma, acho que existem sim usuários exemplares que merecem respeito da parte da moderação e da empresa. E não é porque tem 100k de rep, mas pela constante utilização do sistema de forma útil, respeitosa, dentro das regras. Mas pelo jeito tudo já foi esclarecido com ele, então acho que... sei lá... deixa pra lá imho...

Comment: Eu tirei o texto e não removi nada porque houve uma tentativa de desqualificar o que postei. Tentativa essa usando a mesma técnica que fui acusado de usar. Quando percebi que ali não estava havendo um diálogo, achei melhor retirar algo que não produziria nenhum resultado. Eu posso errar, mas o meu objetivo é sempre tentar o melhor do site. Mantenho minhas convicções, mas não acho que um debate sobre aquilo vá provocar algo positivo, então é melhor deixar pra lá. Tirei para evitar o que está acontecendo agora. Ter pessoas que se aproveitam para gerar polêmica.