# Votos negativos deveriam ter custo mais alto?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, qualidade, experiência

> Esta postagem se originou [desta resposta original](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4848/73), como parte da
>   discussão a respeito de como melhorar a percepção dos usuários com
>   relação às experiências ruins no site. Por favor, dê a sua opinião a
>   respeito desta sugestão particular.

**Votos negativos deveriam ter custo mais alto**. Votar é importante pelos argumentos que eu já descrevi anteriormente. Faz parte do mecanismo estigmérgico que o sistema usa. E, muito embora os votos positivos e negativos tenham a mesma importância sistêmica e social, os votos negativos são aqueles que prejudicam mais facilmente a experiência dos participantes com a comunidade e com o sistema. O voto negativo já tem hoje um custo, mas eu creio que ele é muito pequeno. As pessoas não precisam votar negativamente para ajudar o sistema a funcionar, pois a ausência de votos positivos têm um efeito similar. Perguntas com mais votos positivos também se destacam de perguntas que têm pouco ou não têm voto algum. Assim, se o voto negativo custasse mais, as pequenas injustiças - mais danosas à experiência - poderiam ser evitadas por mais tempo. Note que isso não resolveria completamente o problema, pois alguém com muita reputação e má intenção ainda poderia pagar o custo apenas pra votar "injustamente" se assim desejasse. Mas reduziria o comportamento meramente estigmático (voto sem pensar muito, apenas porque tá "aparentemente" ruim), porque conectaria o voto a um processo mais racional relacionado à perda significativa de algo como a reputação.

> EDIT:
>
> Eu havia inicialmente acreditado que aumentar o custo dos votos era
>   uma boa, mas os argumentos dos colegas (obrigado pela discussão!) têm
>   me mostrado que esse não é necessariamente o melhor caminho. Uma alternativa
>   que parece mais imediatamente eficaz (e que eu confesso que nem
>   havia percebido como um problema) é trabalhar na sinalização dos
>   votantes quando o conteúdo é editado, para que eles possam voltar à
>   pergunta/resposta e refletir sobre retirar seus votos negativos.

Comment: Aumentar o custo teria quase o mesmo efeito de remover o recurso. Creio, que devemos discutir formas para que seja feito melhor uso do recurso, não aumentar a dificuldade(no caso o custo) de seu uso. Uma solução já feita pelo @Gabe seria a fila de triagem, assim, muitas perguntas recebidas com negativos, teriam a chance de ser melhorada antes mesmo se surgir na pagina principal.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Acho que as duas soluções tratam de 2 problemas diferentes. A triagem é alimentada por um filtro automático, que impede certas perguntas de aparecerem na homepage antes de passarem pela triagem. Isso não impede que algumas coisas não passem pela triagem, ou que sejam mal recebidas mesmo depois triagem. A sugestão do Luiz Vieira tenta lidar com o problema do acúmulo de downvotes em um post (por conta do [mecanismo de estigmergia](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4848) que ele citou, já que, entre outros motivos, não há muita diferença pro site entre -2 e -20 em um post

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Depende de quanto o custo aumenta. Hoje os votos positivos não têm custo algum, enquanto que os negativos têm custo de 2. Talvez seja fácil obter uma consulta sobre a quantidade de votos negativos vs positivos no site, mas a minha intuição me diz que ainda assim (com custo) os votos negativos são maioria. Talvez os membros tendam a ser mais observadores com relação a conteúdo ruim do que a conteúdo bom?

Comment: @LuizVieira acredita que não? Tem uma [resposta aqui no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4852/28595), mostrando que os negativos são bem inferiores aos positivos, apesar de eu também ter pensado como você, que eram bem mais numerosos.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Pois é. Não vejo essa sugestão de aumentar o custo como uma maneira de diminuir o número total de downvotes, mas sim de coibir um pouco certos casos de abuso - voluntários ou não.

Comment: @Gabe Qual a razão para não ter custo em votar negativo nas perguntas?

Comment: You know what man, fluck off com essa história... é como se o mundo estivesse vindo abaixo, "ohhh, o voto negativo", "ó, os ignorantes", "óoo, a injustiça", "porcaria de elitistas"... O que veio primeiro, o voto negativo ou os craques que fazem este site (e os outros)?... Putz... e olha que adoro votar positivo, encontrar solução 10, aquele snippet radical, aquela opinião embasada... Tá a fim de postar lixo, vai pro Yahoo.

Comment: (nada pessoal, Luiz, é que o meme tá me incomodando muito, e ando respondendo com pedra a tal idéia... espero que "fluck" passe no filtro da civilidade, lol) ---ps: encontrar bom conteúdo de respostas é graças às perguntas, das mais ingênuas às mais avançadas, também merecedoras de todos os +1 que posso fazer

Comment: Quero lembrar que o positivo mal dado também é danoso (enaltece maneiras erradas de se resolver problemas). Não vou falar em por preço nele, pois bagunçaria bem a mecânica do site, mas acho que o importante é entendermos que "voto irresponsável é ruim", não importa o "sinal". "Abrasileirar" o SOpt no sentido de se votar menos negativo é transformar o nosso oásis em mais do mesmo deserto. Os problemas "pontuais" devem ser tratados com melhor informação e educação (como quase tudo). **Comentei para fazer contraponto c/ a discussão toda, não em oposição ao post do @LuizVieira**.

Comment: Não levo a mal não, @brasofilo. :) Eu só acho que se algo incomoda muita gente, então ela deve ser levada um pouco a sério. Só isso.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Bom, posso estar enganado, mas essa postagem contabiliza o número de perguntas com votos positivos/negativos. Isso não quer dizer necessariamente que as pessoas votem mais positivamente do que negativamente. De qualquer forma, pode ser que isso seja mesmo uma inverdade (como eu disse, era uma intuição, que pode estar errada mesmo). Mas não muda o fato de que a percepção de receber votos negativos é bem ruim para usuários novatos.

Comment: Bem lembrado, @Bacco. Também é danoso. Mas me parece que a discussão anda mais voltada à percepção ruim, principalmente por parte de usuários mais novos (recém-chegados ao site).

Comment: @LuizVieira até por isso que eu destaquei não ser um contraponto ao seu post, entendo que são ângulos diferentes do problema. Cheguei a comentar em outra ocasião que um post negativado talvez merecesse um aviso desses amarelos (igual ao do fechamento, mas só para o autor) com um texto do tipo "Seu post recebeu algumas negativações. Isto pode significar (texto que aponta os problemas, mas de maneira ao usuário entender que faz parte de um sistema maior + sugestões de melhoria)". Seria uma tentativa de não caracterizar ataque pessoal, e avisar que aquilo é algo "normal". (tou só complementando)

Comment: Quanto ao custo mais alto, poderia ser o caso, mas isso parte de um pressuposto que usuários com rep mais alta são mais conscientes pra votar (pois pra estes, o efeito do preço seria menos eficaz como forma de coibir negativos). Se não for o caso, pode gerar um desequilíbrio no comportamento das pessoas com pouca rep. De qualquer forma, acho a discussão totalmente relevante, e crua o suficiente para justificar este levantamento de questionamentos como você tem feito, para que surjam novas idéias e argumentos a favor e contra.

Comment: @Bacco Entendo. Mas quando eu digo mais alta não é necessariamente algo impagável a ponto de limitar o voto apenas às pessoas com rep mais alta. O pressuposto não é esse, e sim de que negativar tem custo. Hoje *já tem* (2 pontos perdidos por voto negativo, se eu não me engano), mas esse custo não é tão percebido pelos usuários que as vezes votam negativamente quando poderiam, de forma alternativa, apenas comentar ou mesmo votar pra fechar.

Comment: @Bacco Em outras palavras, eu enxergo distinções importantes entre conteúdo ruim e pergunta mal-formulada. O segundo é mais facilmente corrigido e não necessariamente merece imediatamente um voto negativo.

Comment: @LuizVieira custa apenas 1 pra quem vota. Deste seu comentário, me surgiu outra possibilidade: Ao se negativar, talvez uma pergunta questionando o votante se é caso de negativo mesmo, ou se não seria melhor pedir mais detalhes (voto para fechar como não claro), etc. Isto sugeriria o negativo como uma alternativa entre várias ações, em vez da "agressão cumulativa" de sinalizar, votar pra fechar e ainda negativar. Mais ou menos a triagem, mas levantada individualmente. Acho que o site tem espaço sobrando para inovações deste tipo, para se criar um "processo de votação", em vez de um mero clique.

Comment: @Bacco É uma ideia. Na prática também penaliza um pouco mais o voto negativo, só que essa penalização está no desempenho da interação ao invés de na reputação. Mas eu admito que não sou muito fã de prejudicar o desempenho da interação.

Comment: @LuizVieira de fato é uma burocracia intencional. Não gosto quando acontece por acidente ou falta da devida atenção do programador, mas acho que tem seu lugar, dependendo do "projeto".

Comment: @LuizVieira mostre que incomoda muita gente. A solução para os novatos não se sentirem mal é o sistema informá-los do que está acontecendo, não deixá-lo no escuro. O sistema deve informar de forma clara que aquilo não é pessoal, não é necessariamente ruim, que a pergunta não está afundada, que pode ser revertido, enfim, a solução pode não ser simples, pode não ser perfeita, mas quando se deseja resolver o problema, que é menor do que parece, uma solução existe, o primeiro passo é querer solucionar. Sobre o custo, precisa de uma heurística complexa para determiná-lo. Ficaria longo falar nisso.

Comment: Note que no passado o voto negativo em pergunta tinha custo, hoje não tem mais. A SE mandou uma mensagem clara que ela quer que negativos em perguntas são bem vistos, mais que em reposta. O custo do negativo em resposta existe mais para evitar que o negativo seja dado por estratégia. Eu não sei o que pode ser feito para "conscientizar" o usuário para negativar só quando o conteúdo é ruim. Tem gente que até confessa que vota sem ler, porque o post é de tal pessoa. Algumas coisas podem ajudar, mas mais cedo ou mais tarde a pessoa que quer votar errado conseguirá fazer isso sem preocupações.

Comment: Eu acho que tem até espaço para acabar com o negativo. Desde que seja fácil filtrar/remover o conteúdo ruim. O negativo nem é um mecanismo eficaz para coibir conteúdo ruim.

Comment: Isso mesmo @bigow. Pra mim seria muito interessante alguma forma do sistema avisar que um post em que votei negativo foi editado. Muitas vezes votei negativo num post ruim, depois ele foi editado e melhorado, eu não fico sabendo e meu negativo fica lá, eternamente, quando eu poderia retirá-lo.

Comment: @Earendul sim, eu acho que o sistema pode ajudar evitar as falhas não intencionais de várias formas. O humano é falho, o sistema não é. Claro que ele não vai substituir o julgamento, não vai coibir o uso errado, mas vai ajudar a pessoa fazer o certo, vai informar para que ela acerte. E aí quando ela errar será mais fácil detectar a má intenção. Qualquer tentativa de conscientizar o usuário terá que ser feito pelo sistema de forma adequada no momento que o usuário está agindo. Post não meta não atinge a maioria das pessoas, comentário depois que a ação foi realizada é tarde demais.

Comment: @Earendul "Pra mim seria muito interessante alguma forma do sistema avisar que um post em que votei negativo foi editado". Cara, isso ai sim é uma coisa boa. Sugiro abrir uma postagem só pra isso, pois eu realmente acho que é uma ideia interessante.

Comment: @bigown Bom, eu concordo plenamente que o sistema deve informar claramente as ocorrências. E ele já informa quando um voto (seja negativo ou positivo) é recebido (aparece a notificação da perda/ganho de rep e a indicação da postagem onde ocorreu). Eu também acho que negativos são importantes, tanto quanto positivos. Como eu expliquei no post original, é a minha opinião que esse modelo de comportamento coletivo funciona como filtro de conteúdo no longo prazo. A proposta é só para tentar melhorar a experiência individual no curto prazo.

Comment: Apenas para me juntar àqueles que acham que os votantes em determinada pergunta/resposta deveriam ser notificados das edições e que, para diminuir o impacto que tem nos novatos os votos negativos, "O sistema deve informar de forma clara que aquilo não é pessoal,..."(@bigown). Talvez(não tenho a certeza) se o voto negativo em perguntas tivesse custo pudesse evitar/minimizar alguns excessos.

Comment: @LuizVieira não é bem assim, oje o sistema tenta esconder que a pessoa recebeu negativo. Claro que não tem como esconder de vez, o que mostra como é uma tentativa que nem deveria ser feita. Seria melhor uma informação clara, transparente e informativa do que aconteceu ali. Eu discordo que os negativos estão funcionando. Ele nem filtra adequadamente o conteúdo ruim e nem ajuda a pessoa melhorar, embora seria esta a intenção. Só cria atrito. Acho que esta proposta **pode** até resolver **um** problema do negativo, mas não **o** problema.

Comment: @ramaral quando tinha custo se votava menos. O problema do custo é que ele evita os bons negativos também. Se bobear mais que os excessos. Não tenho certeza mas acho que o custo distorce mais do que ajuda. Mas sem o custo não ajuda tanto também. Ou pelo menos não resolve o problema de vez. Ainda mais quando há campanha para não se negativar. As pessoas não negativam o suficiente nem o que é ruim, quando se faz campanha para evitar ainda mais, o que acontece é que o negativo perde efeito, aí é melhor nem ter e criar outro mecanismo.

Comment: Claro que a intenção é apenas fazer o negativo ser usado corretamente. Mas a prática mostra que isto não funciona. É mais ou menos com a discussão de socialismo e capitalismo. É claro que o socialismo é algo excelente. Se todos os seres humanos concordarem em agir favoravelmente a isto. Como isto é uma enorme ilusão, não funciona, e aí ficamos impedidos de avançar no que temos, porque as pessoas ficam buscando o ótimo inviável quando podemos ter o razoável viável.

Comment: @bigown Sim, daí o meu "talvez". O melhor será não gastarmos as nossas energias a tentar evitar o voto mal dado mas sim promover/encontrar formas para que o voto seja melhor entendido, não só por quem o dá mas também por quem o recebe.

Comment: @ramaral perfeito. É possível até tentar evitar o voto mal dado, mas discursos no meta ou chat não são eficazes para isto. O sistema precisa ativamente fazer o que dá para fazer.

Comment: @bigown Não entendi. Como o sistema tenta esconder o voto negativo? Sempre que eu recebo votos negativos eles são bem claros pra mim. De todas as formas, concordo que é melhor gastar energias em tentar melhorar o entendimento do que penalizar quem vota.

Comment: @LuizVieira ele não notifica o usuário que recebeu o negativo. Claro que ele pode ativamente verificar que isto ocorreu, mas não ocorre o mesmo que ocorre com o positivo. Em geral eu só percebo quando eu resolvo entrar pra ver a reputação do dia, coisa que poucos fazem (os mais ativos fazem sempre) ou quando recebo outro positivo, aí aparece o +8 ao invés de +10. Não esconde bem. Nem tem como. Seria útil até a pessoa receber esse *feedback* para imediatamente ver se tem algo a fazer para melhorar a situação. Eu mesmo já tomei + negativos porque tomei 1 negativo e não fui notificado p/ melhorar

Comment: @bigown Admito que eu não sabia. A impressão que eu tive foi que sempre mostrava da mesma forma como os positivos, com um aviso de que se perdeu rep na pergunta tal. É, se não mostra isso, também acho que está ai um grande problema.

Comment: Negativar virou bagunça, tem que aumentar, ao menos se votar negativo no mesmo dia, ex: 1 voto -1, segundo voto -3, terceiro -5 e assim por diante.

Answer (score 13):

Na minha opinião, **eles já tem um custo alto**.

Para ter direito a votar negativo, a pessoa precisa ganhar 25 votos em uma pergunta, ou 13 votos numa resposta. Parece pouquinho para quem já frequenta tem tempo, mas é um bom desafio para quem chega.

Quando me cadastrei na Stack Exchange foi porque cliquei no +1 para uma resposta que era exatamente o que precisava e o sistema me avisou que precisava me registrar. Uma vez registrado, vi que precisava de [15 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) para votar positivo.

Depois de alcançar os 15 e poder votar positivamente, encontrei uma informação no site que me pareceu muito errada e **tentei fazer -1**, o sistema me disse que [precisava de 125](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).
Eita!
Então tá, vamos lá.

Respondi mais um tanto e cheguei lá, posso votar -1.
<sup>Pergunta ruim, -1.

Resposta ruim, -1...</sup>
**Opa!** Teve uma **mudança na minha reputação**, tinha 125, agora tenho 124 e não posso mais votar negativo.
Vixi, votar negativo numa resposta custa ponto... e é tão difícil conseguir ponto...
<sub>acho que é difícil enfatizar o suficiente esta mentalidade injetada pelo sistema, "my points, my precious"</sub>

Se eu voto negativo, a pessoa toma -2, se algum outro vota positivo ela leva +5 ou +10.
São necessários muitos mais negativos para contrabalançar um positivo.

> Mesmo tendo 3, 5, 10, 15, 20 mil pontos, o pessoal já custa a negativar... ainda que seja numa pergunta, cuja negativação é *grátis* ou numa resposta que *só custa -1*...
>
> ### Fonte: *https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters*

**A quantidade de downvoters ali é deprimente**. Deprimente de tão baixa... Cinco mil votos e só 80 negativos?

Até poderia fazer uma estatística básica, mas o ônus da prova fica por conta da promotoria. Ou então do Community Manager ou de algum dos Moderadores que faça uma demonstração gráfica, puxando informação privilegiada do banco de dados, comparando com outros sites, e mostrando que **`"a votação aqui segue padrões anormais e que modificar o custo do voto é necessário"`**. Ou basicamente isto aqui vai ficar num "achismo" tremendo e sem nenhuma chance de ir a lugar nenhum.

> > PS: Se uma pergunta tem [-4 no site principal ou -8 no meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261801/how-do-i-see-all-newest-questions-even-negatively-voted-ones-with-the-new-navi/262273#262273), não é mostrada na página principal. Aparentemente, esse é o padrão da rede SE e pode ser configurado site a site. Donde se conclui que uma função do voto negativo é remover o destaque de um post que tem problemas graves.

Comment: `note to self`: falar do custo de votar negativo e fazer um comentário construtivo... jeje, risco de receber grosseria de volta prá lá dos 70%....

Comment: Muito boas colocações. :) Mas esse custo alto é um custo inicial né? Depois que essa "fase" passa, o custo se torna bastante pequeno, não acha? De todas as formas, concordo plenamente contigo que uma análise de dados correta é necessária para não ficarmos no achismo. Realmente, todos nós podíamos votar mais de forma geral. MAs, btw (e desculpe a minha ignorância, por favor), mas eu acho que não sei interpretar a página de votantes que você referenciou. Como vc diferencia ali os votos negativos dos votos positivos dados?

Comment: @LuizVieira Mas aí não seria normal o cara com tempo e uso do site já saber fazer boas escolhas?

Comment: @EMBarbosa Deveria, mas não necessariamente é.

Comment: Acho que a discussão tá perdendo de vista o fenômeno por trás da sugestão do @LuizVieira. Ela não se baseia no fato de que estamos votando *mal*, ou votando contra demais, ou qualquer coisa do tipo. Mas sim na premissa de que em algumas situações (quando algo já está negativado, por ex.) a adição de mais um downvote representa ganho nenhum para o site, mas continua sendo custosa (em rep e psicologicamente) pra quem criou o post. A ideia por trás é que talvez seja possível coibir que algo chegue a -5 ou -10 sem resistência nenhuma.

Comment: Discordo que o custo seja alto. Quem mais visita o site é quem mais tem reputação para jogar fora. Para algumas dessas pessoas, um voto negativo não vale nada e, pela minha experiência nesse site, não vale nem um comentário. Ainda não aconteceu comigo aqui (no em português) de explicarem onde eu teria errado em alguma resposta após votar contra. **Nenhuma vez sequer**. Pode imaginar o quanto isso é frustrante, né. Eu não tenho nenhum problema em me retratar, pedir desculpas etc. Críticas são ótimas no meio técnico porque às vezes não sabemos que não sabemos de algo. Mas não vejo isso aqui.

Comment: @Gabe Downvotes "em manada" são uma das maneiras de "votar mal". Em vez de impedir as pessoas de votar, o sistema deveria encorajá-las a votar bem. Acho furado enfraquecer mais ainda o downvote (ver minha resposta).

Comment: @Luiz, não está a primeira vista, tem que ir no perfil, pedir os detalhes e ali tem o resumo...

Comment: @Gabe, marcar lixo como lixo não é ganho? Pode trazer algumas estatísticas pra discussão? Do tipo: "voto em manada afugenta 90% dos novos usuários"? Estamos falando de um problema real ou de percepções subjetivas?

Comment: @brasofilo Posso procurar pra ver se temos um "problema real" estatísticamente significativo. Mas também acho que o "voto em manada" representa absolutamente 0 de ganho pra comunidade, e não tem porque ser protegido. O que você acha que um -8 faz pelo site que um -2 não pode fazer?

Comment: Talvez o problema para a experiência (principalmente de usuários novatos) não esteja no voto negativo em si, mas naqueles -5 votos que facilmente acompanham as indicações para fechamento. Um estatística que o @Gabe talvez consiga puxar também é quantas perguntas fechadas têm negativos e quantos desses usuários retornaram a postar outras vezes.

Comment: @brasofilo Ainda não entendi e não achei essa informação. O que eu vejo no perfil é a quantidade de votos dados, mas não a distinção entre negativos e positivos dentre estes.

Comment: @Luiz, no rodapé da tab Atividade: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1287812/brasofilo?tab=topactivity

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu estou montando uma query que compara a "probabilidade" de voltar a postar de pessoas que tiveram posts negativados. Infelizmente, não é algo muito trivial de se buscar, mas talvez eu tenha algo pronto amanhã

Comment: @Gabe, talvez a diferença entre "só duas pessoas acharam este conteúdo ruim" e "oito pessoas que se importam com a qualidade do site acham que a pergunta deve ser evaporada o mais rápido possível"? Entre "melhorando é super fácil reverter" e "burn it with fire"?

Comment: @brasofilo Existem maneiras muito mais práticas e rápidas de se lidar com as coisas "burn it with fire". E a diferença que você descreveu presume que os casos de downvotes empilhados sejam em grande maioria justificados, o que certamente não tem evidência

Comment: @brasofilo Ah, agora eu vi. hehehe Obrigado! :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Então o problema está sendo atacado de forma incorreta. Se a questão é que quem tem muita reputação pode pagar facilmente o voto negativo, então o voto talvez devesse custar mais para esses usuários.

Comment: @EMBarbosa Vc diz um custo de voto negativo proporcional ao quanto de reputação um usuário tem? É uma ideia. Mas pelas estatísticas que estão colocando, o voto negativo não parece mesmo ser o principal problema. Eu ainda acho que uma sequencia, mesmo que pequena, de votos negativos em uma pergunta de um usuário novato (que talvez devesse ser fechada ao invés de negativada) [é bem impactante na experiência dele](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112694/criar-um-servidor-php-para-um-bot-de-conversa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-usando-aiml#comment234417_112694).

Comment: @EMBarbosa Mas talvez existam mesmo outras formas de coibir esse problema em especial sem mexer no custo do voto.

Comment: Sim @LuizVieira. Não discordo disso. Mas se a ideia é coibir os muitos votos negativos numa questão de iniciantes, então o problema está sendo atacado de forma incorreta mais uma vez.

Comment: @EMBarbosa Sim, vc tem razão. Eu havia inicialmente acreditado que aumentar o custo dos votos era uma boa, mas os argumentos têm me mostrado que esse não é necessariamente o caminho. Parece que uma alternativa importante é trabalhar na sinalização dos votantes quando o conteúdo é editado (para que eles possam refletir sobre retirar os votos).

Comment: @Gabe, até agora `certamente não tem evidencia` de nada, né? Nem da afirmação nem da negativa... PS: qual a configuração do SOpt para que os [votos negativos removam a pergunta da página frontal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262273/185667)? . . . PS2: [as estatísticas que a bluefeet apresentou](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4852/201) mostram zero problema de negativos no site

Comment: @brasofilo eu disse que os dados não eram tão simples de buscar, e iam demorar um pouco. Mas sim, há um impacto claro da recepção do post inicial na probabilidade de alguém fazer perguntas subsequentes. Os números da bluefeet mostram que não temos downvotes demais, o que não quer dizer que todos os downvotes são aplicados da melhor maneira possível, ou que não tem impacto sobre a comunidade, que são os 2 pontos pertinentes à essa discussão

Comment: Voto negativo assusta e inibe usuários novatos.

Answer (score 9):

Eu não acho que aumentar o custo seja um bom caminho. Idealmente, esses votos nem deveriam ter custo, ou então não deveriam existir, por uma questão de coerência. A existência do custo, mesmo simbólico como ele é hoje, vai inevitavelmente inteferir no que deveria ser o principal objetivo desse tipo de voto: ajudar a classificar os conteúdos. Se o voto tem custo, ele é menos usado – e de fato temos [1 negativo para cada 8 positivos](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/434900), o que não parece ser tanto.

Também a barreira de entrada para sequer poder votar negativo é maior, como mostrou o @brasofilo, o que já configura um duplo desencorajamento dos negativos no sistema. A esse desencorajamento somam-se fatores culturais e comportamentais que fazem pessoas deixarem de negativar para que o outro não se sinta agredido ou frustrado. Avaliações negativas são naturalmente frustrantes para qualquer um, e o sistema procura amenizar essa frustração, tanto ao desincentivar o voto, quanto ao omitir do autor da postagem que ela foi negativada – o sistema discretamente notifica um `+8` na lista de realizações se sua resposta tiver +1/-1, mas não notifica `-2` no caso de +0/-1.

Então, para tentar coibir abusos e evitar frustrações, os votos negativos já são bastante desencorajados. Isso prejudica sua função como qualificadores de conteúdo. Se for para aumentar ainda mais as barreiras, melhor abolir os negativos de uma vez, pois ele se tornariam ainda menos representativos na determinação da qualidade e relevância dos conteúdos.

Pessoalmente sou contra o fim dos negativos; prefiro o atual sistema ternário, no qual a ausência de voto representa um ponto "neutro" entre positivo e negativo, a um sistema binário, com apenas +1 ou ausência de voto. Concordo com os que estão propondo aproveitar a "oportunidade" para informar melhor as pessoas sobre o que representam as avaliações negativas e como evitá-las. O @Bacco sugeriu [mostrar um aviso informativo em publicações negativadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4857/votos-negativos-deveriam-ter-custo-mais-alto#comment16234_4857), o que é uma boa idéia.  O sistema deveria se antecipar à frustração (inevitável, só varia em grau!) que vai causar e tentar informar o melhor possível o que está acontecendo. Deve-se também procurar alguma maneira de informar melhor quem vota, para evitar enganos e abusos. O @utluiz acaba de postar [uma sugestão para lidar com isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4865).

Comment: Ótimas colocações. E obrigado pela consulta do *up-down-ratio*. Novamente eu admito que eu não sabia corretamente o funcionamento do sistema em relação à informação do negativo ocorrido. Considerando isso tudo, eu tendo a acreditar que o problema realmente não está no custo do voto negativo (eu também sou contra seu fim), mas ná má informação de sua ocorrência. Não notificar nada no caso de +0/-1 é ruim porque o autor não tem a menor chance de perceber a possível má qualidade do conteúdo.

Comment: Também acho isto. Já havia concordado com o brasofilo. Acho que poderia se fazer algumas coisas paliativas, como é o caso do custo do negativo. Mas todas elas não resolverão problemas. A mudança para que o negativo seja muito bem informado, notificado com detalhes pelo menos p/ os novatos, com transparência, é fundamental para o sistema evoluir e evitar reações exageradas pelo menos das pessoas razoáveis.

Answer (score -4):

Custei, mas acho que entendi qual o propósito dessa questão.

- O problema **não é** o custo dos votos negativos. Isso poderia ser resolvido com a questão proposta. Mas o custo [já é alto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4862/2652).
- O problema **não é** ter muita reputação e poder pagar o custo dos votos negativos com facilidade. Isso poderia ser resolvido com votos negativos terem custos relativos a reputação.
- O problema **não é** existirem votos negativos. Isso poderia ser resolvido [removendo os votos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4868/2652) negativos do site.

A questão é que quando um **usuário iniciante** recebe muitos votos negativos ele pode se sentir desencorajado a continuar participando do site porque ele não sabe o motivo de ter recebido tantos votos negativos. Isso é frustrante, nem tanto pelo impacto negativo em sua reputação...

Isso provavelmente a maior parte de nós tenha passado uma vez ou outra. Então a questão não é combater os votos negativos, mas diminuir o impacto que uma chuva de votos negativos no site principal possa ter sobre o usuário iniciante.

Neste caso, o sistema deveria tratar o impacto. Algumas sugestões:

1. Descontar valor máximo na reputação de um usuário iniciante por questão que ele fizer se não for reincidente;
2. Mostrar votos negativos até um máximo. Exemplo a questão pode ter vinte votos negativos, mas será sempre mostrado no máximo "-6" a menos que o usuário tenha reputação suficiente para entender o que está acontecendo;
3. Notificar quem negativou a pergunta|resposta de edições **significativas** na pergunta|resposta (já proposto [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4863/2652));

Comment: Chuva de votos negativos não é o problema, o problema é os usuários entenderem o modelo do site. Muitos novatos que começam a participar ativamente aqui não entendem bem o modelo e presumem que eles podem inventar suas próprias regras. Votos negativos são feitos para ser usado, se a pergunta tem um problema o voto tem que ser usado, eu vejo muito voto positivo mal usado, mas ae ninguém reclama, o problema mesmo que que existe um FAQ, mas quase ninguém se preocupa em entender ele ou mesmo sabe que ele existe. Realmente concordo contigo que deveriam haver ferramentas para notificar edições...

Comment: ... Mas ainda sim isso só iria amenizar um pouco, pois o problema é o entendimento do "modelo do site" e as pessoas que querem inventar regras ou ditar o certo e o errado sem entender o modelo.

Comment: Eu concordo contigo @GuilhermeNascimento que os novatos não entendem o modelo do site e foi exatamente por isso que concordei inicialmente com os dois posts do bfavaretto e do brasofilo. Mas isso não significa que recepcioná-los com muitos negativos seja algo, perdoe o trocadilho, positivo. A questão é tentar limitar o impacto inicial de uma negativação em massa num usuário iniciante para que ele seja incentivado a aprender as regras e não para que ele nunca volte mais ao site.

Comment: Então, mas eu não disse que negativar vai ser positivo e não estou me referindo aos novatos que entraram ontem, o problema é que tem usuário até com 3k que também não entende o modelo do site, tem muita pergunta que bastava fechar, nem precisava negativar, mas os caras só dão downvotes, mas não fecham. Quero dizer que tem muito usuário que não entende o modelo em vários quesitos, note que o modelo é bem amplo e fala de várias coisas e áreas do site ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, concordo mais uma vez. Mas aí já é outra história... O que está sendo discutido aqui e que, admito, eu custei a entender é o impacto que a negativação em massa tem sobre os iniciantes. (: Foi isso que fez o Luiz fazer o post inicial. Veja os comentários do Gabe aí a cima. Eu só mencionei o que eu penso que poderia minimizar o impacto. Mas não creio que isso **por si só** resolva o problema.

Comment: então eu sei disso, mas é ae que eu quero chegar, vai minimizar o "minimo", porque mesmo que ambos problemas pareçam diferentes ainda sim um é a raiz do outro, chuva de negativos nos novatos ocorre mesmo por isto, o MODELO, links: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice (veja que esse link pertence ao modelo) e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing - sei que parecem não ter haver, mas é assim, tem muita coisa que basta dar uma editada, nem precisa negativar, tem muita coisa que você pode sim negativar, mas comente de maneira respeitosa o problema, isso é parte do modelo...

Comment: ...e a maioria nunca leu o modelo, nem mesmo muitos usuários com mais de 3k leram, tem muita gente com alta pontuação que quando vou fazer uma critica construtiva fica todo nervosinho e começa de mimimi, mas eles deveriam seguir o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice - agora pergunto eles sabem o que é isso? Acho que não :/ - Tá ae o problema, existe um modelo, existem regras, existe o META com dicas de comportamentos saudaveis, mas raramente alguem segue isso, só usuários extremamente participativos o fazem...

Comment: ... Veja esse link: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4871/3635 - **Pra mim** tudo isto de votos/falta de fechamento comentar ou não está ocorrendo pela falta de interesse da maioria que já participa do site.