# Notificação de votos negativos

Tags: novo-recurso, status-revisão

Diante da discussão gerada na pergunta [Votos negativos deveriam ter custo mais alto?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/14674) surgiram pelo menos três sugestões que, ao meu ver, trariam benefícios ao sistema, principalmente no que se refere a votos negativos:

- O sistema avisar que algum post em que você votou negativo sofreu alterações. Assim você poderia retirar o voto caso a edição melhorasse o post;
- O sistema avisar de forma clara que você recebeu um voto negativo e não apenas quando recebe votos positivos. Assim você ficaria sabendo que seu post deve ser melhorado e consequentemente poderá ser retirado(s) o(s) voto(s) negativos;
- O sistema avisar quando você receber voto negativo que trata-se apenas de um mecanismo do sistema para que você possa melhora o post, e assim, diminuir o "efeito negativo" do voto negativo.

O que acham? Será alguma coisa pode ser implementada no sistema?

<sub><sub>Desabafo: até hoje nunca vi nada ser aceito e mudado no sistema por pedidos da comunidade, além de questões estéticas. Será que estou perdendo meu tempo com este post? Também não acho que estas sugestões devam necessariamente ser aprovadas, mas pelo menos algo de bom sair daqui, e não ficar apenas nas discussões :p</sub></sub>

Comment: A primeira sugestão seria excelente, poderiam até colocar uma margem de 24hrs do voto, ou coisa parecida. Se a função do negativo é apontar questões que precisam ser melhoradas, nada mais justo que serem removidos quando é apresentado o esforço do melhoramento.

Comment: Há um tempo eu perguntei como [ver os votos negativos que dei](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2663/4808) justamente para fazer o que você citou no primeiro ponto. Seria ótimo o sistema notificar quando houvesse edições, ao invés de checar a lista uma vez por semana para ver se algum negativo deve ser removido. :P

Comment: seria excelente se essa primeira sugestão existisse de fato.

Comment: Ótimo resumo. E, mesmo que nada seja aceito ou mudado, não acho que você está perdendo o seu tempo. No mínimo, se nada mudar e algum dia um membro se sentir injustiçado, ele pode vir até aqui e perceber que nós tentamos melhorar a experiência para todos. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira isso mesmo, nós tentamos. Nossa parte nós fizemos.

Comment: Apoiado 100%. Quando tinha mais tempo nas mãos, costumava revisar meus votos negativos pra ver se mereciam mudança... Relevante: [Should you be notified if something you vote on is edited? Why can you change your vote after something's been edited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135626/185667) e [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343/185667)

Comment: Saúdo o facto destas sugestões passarem a **status-revisão**

Comment: @ramaral Estamos trabalhando na primeira delas, especificamente. Como o brasofilo disse, ela já foi sugerida algumas vezes e sempre foi rejeitada/ignorada. To tentando criar um formato que resolva a maioria dos problemas que ela já teve, pra gente poder finalmente implementar algo assim.

Comment: voto negativo virou brincadeira nesse site. quaquer coisa é motivo para voto negativo

Comment: Gostei da primeira sugestão.

Answer (score 26):

É algo que sinto falta desde o começo, principalmente o primeiro item.

## Notificação de edição de post negativado

Quando dou um negativo, eu tento deixar a página aberta por algum tempo para ver se há alguma mudança.

Só que o processo é manual e, com a quantidade de conteúdo que lidamos todos os dias, dentro e fora do SO, é complicado ficar olhando a aba várias vezes e fácil de esquecer do contexto.

Acredito que todos os que votam negativo com o objetivo de ajudar a comunidade classificando o conteúdo estariam dispostos a revisar o seu voto se a pergunta fosse boa.

## Notificação de negativo e natureza da mensagem

As demais sugestões fazem parte de uma mesma modificação, que acho ser bom principalmente para os iniciantes.

Ao invés de um seco `-1`, seria interessante dizer ao usuário que a votação na postagem dele indica que ele deveria melhorar o conteúdo.

Isso poderia ser baseado não somente em um simples negativo, mas talvez numa lógica simples mas um pouco mais elaborada. Um exemplo:

- Notificar se o saldo dos votos é negativo.
- Notificar se o saldo for positivo, mas houver pelo menos 50% de negativos, pois isso significa que uma parcela dos usuários viu algum problema.

Existem alguns casos extremos onde uma postagem recebe muitos votos, mas somente poucos contrários à maioria. Com esses casos acho que não é necessário se preocupar, pois se é algo não óbvio geralmente as pessoas deixam comentários.

## Conteúdo da mensagem

O conteúdo da notificação para o usuário, precisa ser sempre amigável, sugerindo melhoria e nunca dando a entender que há algum tipo de punição.

Sobre isso, acabei escrevendo mais algumas ideias numa nova pergunta:

> [Deveríamos qualificar os votos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4865/227)

Comment: Eu acho que tem tudo que eu concordo aqui... Só não vejo a necessidade da mensagem de que o voto negativo trata apenas de um mecanismo no site. Talvez se fosse uma mensagem na primeira vez que toma o negativo tudo bem. Mas ficar sempre dizendo isso, acho desnecessário.

Answer (score 11):

Estamos trabalhando numa alternativa para a primeira sugestão do post original: Como deixar alguém saber que um downvote dado pode ser revisado.

Isso já foi [sugerido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751) [algumas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180667) [vezes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180056) no [passado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139270/), de diversas formas diferentes. E depois de ler tudo que eu podia e pegar dados suficientes, a ideia de ter uma notificação, automática ou não, não é viável.

Uma notificação automática (para todos que votaram contra um post antes de uma edição) geraria 2600 notificações/dia no Stack Overflow em inglês. Em todos os outros sites, inclusive o SOpt, teríamos em torno de 20/dia. O número geral não é tão ruim, mas no SOen é inviável.

Uma notificação não-automática (dependendo de votantes pedindo para serem notificados, ou editores pedindo para notificar) tem um imenso potencial para ser abusada.

No final das contas a ideia de implementar algo assim é exercer alguma mudança no comportamento da comunidade. No caso, aumentar o número de reversões de votos contrários e, indiretamente, talvez aumentar o número e qualidade de edições se mostrarmos que elas tem consequências concretas.

Essa sinalização perde efetividade e eficiência se ela se tornar chata ou inconveniente.

Estamos pensando então no seguinte:

O perfil tem uma seção com os nossos [votos contra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote). A ideia é usar essa seção e permitir que ela seja ordenada por "edição mais recente", mostrando os posts que sofreram alterações.

Além disso, seria mostrado um resumo do conjunto de edições no post desde que você votou:

[image: Resumão da Rodada]

Assim você pode ter uma noção mais rápida de quais posts vale a pena avaliar primeiro, já que um que tenha sofrido uma alteração profunda tem mais chances de ter consertado um problema do que outro que só tenha consertado a formatação do código.

Eventualmente podemos trabalhar em uma maneira de optar por receber notificações quando o número de posts nessa seção ultrapasse um certo valor, ou quando um post já tiver tido alguns outros votos revertidos. Mas isso fica pro futuro.

Por enquanto, o que acham dessa ideia? Não é um aviso, mas permite que as pessoas interessadas em acompanhar o resultado dos seus votos tenham uma maneira bem mais prática de fazê-lo.

Comment: Excelente essa forma, assim fica tudo centralizado num lugar de facil acesso, em nossos perfis, até porque notificações as vezes a gente clica no inbox e elas esmaecem, e deixamos pra olhar depois(quem recebe muitas citações e edições por exemplo) e acabamos esquecendo. Só fiquei em uma dúvida no exemplo, o que é `50% edited`? Metade dos caracteres foram removidos/alterados em uma revisão?

Comment: @DiegoF Eu tirei a foto da proposta no MSE. To conversando com os devs sobre como a gente pode calcular a abrangência de uma edição, e só vou ter detalhes semana que vem.

Comment: Gabe entendi, de qualquer forma, só de ter que o post sofreu uma revisão como na primeira linha do exemplo, já seria ótimo.