# Quantas possibilidade eu tenho de recuperar e melhorar a qualidade de minhas perguntas ja passadas

Tags: debate, suporte, comportamento, proposta-para-faq

Antes de mais nada, quero deixar claro a todos os caros colegas, amigos e amizades que possa surgir ao longo do tempo que permanecer aqui no pt.stackoverflow.com que não estou reclamando de ninguém e muito menos dos "downvote" até porque hoje entendo pra que eles servem e, por isso venho com essa questão a frente, tentar realizar melhorias a antigos e futuros tópico que eu venha abrir na comunidade pt.stackoverflow.com.

Fiz uma lista, digamos assim do que já questionei quando iniciante no pt.stackoverflow.com e não obtive tanto sucesso. Acesse:

[Como buscar um elemento no XML usando JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180595/como-buscar-um-elemento-no-xml-usando-javascript)

[Como realizar uma buscar interna pelo id?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184662/como-realizar-uma-buscar-interna-pelo-id)

[Como Submeter Formulário De Outra Página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142337/como-submeter-formulario-de-outra-p%C3%A1gina)

[redirecionar pagina de erro 404 com Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130420/redirecionar-pagina-de-erro-404-com-javascript)

[Inserir um loop dentro de outro loop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122436/inserir-um-loop-dentro-de-outro-loop)

[Fazer loop percorrer de 20 em 20 linhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126987/fazer-loop-percorrer-de-20-em-20-linhas)

---

É .. nota-se que tive alguns pontos mau detalhados, até porque não sabia por muita das vezes aplicar a [terminologia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminologia) adequada ao que buscava se alcançar como resposta. Infelizmente ganhei esses "downvote" e alguns comentários que julguei ser inadequados. À saber:

- Possivelmente duplicada
- Seu código é mau identado, fica difícil te ajudar
- Eu ia te responder mas você já voto
- Nossa cara você pergunta e responde também
- Ah desculpa, não posso responder agora porque sou lerdo
- Apaguei a minha solução porque você já escolheu a de outro
- Achei que sua pergunta fosse importante, mas não é, por isso dei downvote
- Algumas pessoas não são tolerante ao ler uma pergunta com erros ortográfico e de gramática
  etc...

No final de junho - julho 2017, resolvi me ausentar em alguns períodos, sem interagir com a frequência o qual era acostumado. Fiquei na retaguarda a observar. Decidi por fazer pesquisa on-line sem consultar a comunidade.

Mas deixando certos [infortúnios](https://www.dicio.com.br/infortunio/) de lado, estou voltando aos poucos e queria dar um *upgrade* se possível é claro.

Conto com a interação de vocês aqui nesta questão. Por favor, não deixem de partilhar e compartilhar como é que você faria ou mudaria o título da pergunta assim como seu contexto. Essa citação é importante para mim, para que eu possa crescer profissionalmente.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se você recebeu negativos na sua pergunta e teve o cuidado de a **re-analizar criticamente** e não consegue concluir qual é a falha na sua pergunta você pode e deve trazer a sua pergunta para o meta.

Você pode fazer isto se voce recebeu negativos na sua pergunta e **tomou uma acção** => (editou a pergunta com mais detalhes, ou clarificou os aspetos em falta). Mais uma vez, seja critico nas suas edições.

Os usuários do meta irão-lhe então explicar quais são mais concretamente as falhas nas suas perguntas e, caso não encontrarem nenhuma, muitas vezes eles optarão por compensar os votos negativos por ter manifestado interesse em melhorar o seu conteúdo.

Eu já fiz isso com perguntas anteriormente feitas por mim.

---

Já agora aproveito a resposta para por a prática por mim sugerida em funcionamento. Repare que esta é somente a minha opinião.

[Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130420) manifesta alguma falta de esforço. 
Sempre que for possível voce deve sempre tentar alguma coisa.
De preferência um [mcve](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel?rq=1)

[Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122436) está um pouco melhor porque você tentou alguma coisa mas não dá para ter a certeza o que voce está a tentar fazer. Tente ser mais descriptivo no resultado que você deseja obter.

[Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126987) está boa, eu dei +1.

[Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180595) está muito boa, eu dei +1.

[Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184662) parece ser duplicada da anterior.

[Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142337) acho que teve um bocado de dificuldade em transmitir o seu problema e teve a infelicidade de apresentar um problema impossível de resolver (pelo menos com javascript a correr no browser). Talvez devesse ter feito um pouco mais de pesquisa.

Comment: Boa Bruno! Dica valiosa que não havia se passado pela minha cabeça. Mas agora, sabendo disso, concerteza trarei qualquer pergunta que julgar boa o suficiente para o SO. E trarei para Corte, e com unhas e dentes  vou defender a tese - porque deve permanecer sem fechar ou rebaixar. Só preciso de um advogado pra me auxiliar no processo, se você topar tá valendo hein?!

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Nao me queira como advogado porque nem sei sequer muitas vezes defender o meu próprio interesse! :p

Comment: kkk, sem problema. rsrs [risos]

Answer (score 15):

Ótimo, você não está só se tornando um usuário da comunidade melhor, mas um profissional melhor, está aprendendo a trabalharem equipe, se adaptar ao ambiente em que está, esteja ele certo ou errado, está se comunicando, agindo de forma positiva e procurando por soluções em vez de problemas.

Não sei se entendi bem o que deseja saber, se é algo mais técnico, você pode melhorar sempre. Se é algo de probabilidade não tenho como informar, mas eu diria que a chance é razoável de conseguir melhor resultado se fizer adequadamente. Infelizmente não posso dizer que a chance é ótima porque o que passou tem menos chances. Hoje a comunidade não está tão atenta quanto estava no passado, mas a chance não é ruim, ainda mais tendo postado aqui :) O ideal seria até já ter melhorado.

Todos esses motivos que deram são reais? Não me lembro de ter visto a maioria, e acho que alguns estranhos. Ou isso é o que você acha? Algumas de fato não são motivos para negativar, fechar ou mesmo não responder.

Pelo que analisai os negativos que você tem são injustos. Isto é uma falha da ferramenta associada com a letargia da comunidade. Suas postagens originais eram terríveis e os negativos foram merecidos, mas depois consertou e não só os negativos deveriam ser retirados, como muitas vezes deveriam se transformar em positivos, até mesmo como incentivo pelo esforço, como prêmio por ter feito o correto, por ter evoluído, aprendido, claro, não só por isto, é porque agora o conteúdo está bom, não pode ser um positivo só por consolo.

Poucas vezes vi algum tão bem intencionado e esforçado aqui. Não vou negar, não gosto da atitude dos que se convencionou chamar de millennials de não assumir responsabilidade de nada, é um alento ver alguém procurando ser protagonista da sua própria história.

De fato muitas pessoas acabam desanimando porque melhoram o conteúdo e não obtém um retorno adequado. A comunidade age mal quando vota baseado no que já está votado e não por sua própria análise crítica. Mas reforço que a ferramenta não ajuda adequadamente.

Ela deve facilitar que o conteúdo ruim seja avaliado adequadamente o mais rápido possível, mas também deve facilitar para a situação ser revertida quando o conteúdo passa ser bom. A ferramenta conta que a comunidade vai agir certo, o que não ocorre na maioria das vezes, precisa incentivar, precisa tornar isto algo muito importante, precisa mostrar ao usuário que ele precisa melhorar o conteúdo dele e que isto sempre será recompensado.

Não adianta fazer discurso de melhor recepção dos novatos. Mudar humanos não é fácil, tem que "manipulá-los". Tem que fazer eles irem para o caminho certo, meio como gado :) É, a analogia parece ruim, mas é assim que nós funcionamos mesmo. Temos que por a tecnologia a nosso favor para resolver os problemas, não para criar novos. Se as pessoas não estão indo pelo caminho certo e a ferramenta não está fazendo sua parte é culpa dela.

Para fazer a internet um lugar melhor a ferramenta precisa evoluir, ela já não atende mais as demandas atuais. Ela é 3.0 ou 2.0 e estamos na na sociedade 4.0.

Vamos ver se a comunidade age bem agora que sabem da situação. tenho medo de novamente acontecer efeito manda ao contrário :)

Comment: Vou Parafrasear alguns pontos que você mencionou - *[...] Hoje a comunidade não está tão atenta quanto estava no passado [...] reforço que a ferramenta não ajuda adequadamente [...]* 
Sim, é verdade. Isto é uma deficiência do sistema, concordo plenamente.

*[...] Todos esses motivos que deram são reais? Não me lembro de ter visto a maioria, e acho que alguns estranhos [...]*
Sim são reais, mas grande parte foi removido porquanto **sinalizei** como sendo **rude** e/ou **abusivo**. Minhas Preces foram atendidas. rsrs

Comment: Também concordo, quando você diz - *[...] Suas postagens originais eram terríveis e os negativos foram merecidos, mas depois consertou [...]*
Isso é uma bela duma verdade dita, e compreendida. Nada melhor do que uma dose de bom senso e paciência pra saber lidar [aceitar] =D

*[...] Vamos ver se a comunidade age bem agora que sabem da situação. tenho medo de novamente acontecer efeito manda ao contrário [...]*
Confesso, que tive medo de me expressar sobre os fatos. Antes mesmo de subir essa questão, levei 4 horas imaginando em uma suposta reação ao contrário.

Comment: Bom, ninguém vai atirar em você aqui :) No máximo negativar, dizer que você está errado ;)

Comment: @Maniero, ainda é inviável ter [notificações em votos negativos x edições](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4972/5043)?

Comment: @bio é, isso deveria ser implementado. Ou então acabar com o negativo e prover outro recurso para indicar problemas em um post. Algo assim: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302609/140010

Comment: Sociedade 4.0, humanos 0.1 beta... ( o .1 foi a criação de Eva).

Answer (score 8):

Olá!

Notei que algumas das suas perguntas "nasceram" meio confusas, mas depois você foi lapidando e deixando elas bem claras. Isto é ótimo!

Contudo, uma vez que votaram negativo, **dificilmente alguém volta na sua pergunta editada e melhorada e retira o voto negativo** ou vota positivo. Já [sofri isto no CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/151681/119637), na qual a pergunta até tem código de exemplo completo no Github e continuei com -5 lá.

Infelizmente este é um dos problemas do SO em geral. Você precisa criar a pergunta o mais clara possível desde o começo e nas regras daquele site, caso contrário irá receber vários votos negativos e as possibilidades da sua pergunta permanecer assim, e ainda, espantar visitantes, será enorme.

Por isto, novamente, faço minha crítica ao pessoal com dedo pesado no negativo. Você mesmo é um exemplo de como isto pode espantar os usuários.

Comment: Achei justo sua análise. E confirmo que minhas perguntas - "nasceram confusas" a partir do título. Por exemplo, não sabia o que era paginação, então tentava eu em minha inocência usar a imaginação pra descrever o que pretendia saber. Vou colocar abaixo:

Comment: [De que forma destacar um item do menu ao clicar Voltar ou Avançar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135556/de-que-forma-destacar-um-item-do-menu-ao-clicar-voltar-ou-avan%C3%A7ar) |
[Como faço para desmarcar o radio button anterior após selecionar outro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188272/41467)

Comment: [Como marcar/desmarcar um link numa página clicando sobre avançar/voltar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174732/41467) |
[Criar fluxo de controle na playlist para web player](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174006/criar-fluxo-de-controle-na-playlist-para-web-player)

Comment: Aqui ja esta sabendo qual termo a referenciar. Ja tava na hora né?! rsrs
[Como Fazer Controle Paginado Case/Swictch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137949/41467) |
[De qual maneira poderia esconder demais números de paginação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175157/41467)

Comment: *Notei que algumas das suas perguntas "nasceram" meio confusas, mas depois você foi delapidando e deixando elas bem claras.* - O significado de delapidar não é justamente o contrário?

Comment: @EMBarbosa, vou corrigir :D