# Deveríamos qualificar os votos?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Seguindo a onda de discussão sobre votação, principalmente negativos, após ler a questão sobre [Notificação de votos negativos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4863/227) pensei que talvez  qualificar os votos fosse interessante para direcionar tanto as notificações para o usuário quanto para melhorar o uso do sistema em geral.

Muitos sistemas usam esse mecanismo para melhorar a experiência do usuário. Um dos mais conhecidos provavelmente é o do Facebook, pois você tem a opção "Não quero ver isto" que é seguida de um mini questionário sobre sua motivação.

## Questões para votos positivos

Para votos positivos não há tanto problema, mas ainda assim poderia haver alguma coisa.

Por exemplo, um voto positivo numa questão poderia ser seguido pela pergunta:

> Você acha que esta questão merece destaque?

No meta, isso poderia ser usado para colocar a pergunta com a tag "destaque automaticamente.

No site principal, isso poderia dar um "up" na questão em alguns casos, como quando, por exemplo, ela não tem resposta aceita e já não está mais na página inicial. Isso facilitaria trazer questões não respondidas e boas à tona no caso dela não precisar de uma edição.

## Questões para votos negativos

Ao negativar uma resposta, o sistema poderia trazer, por exemplo, as seguintes opções:

> Por que você acha que esta é uma resposta ruim?
>   [ ] Não gosto do usuário que respondeu
>   [ ] Ela está tecnicamente errada. Deixe um comentário: ....
>   [ ] Incompleta. Deixe um comentário: ....
>   [ ] Formatação ruim
>   [ ] Ela não responde à pergunta
>   [ ] Ela só tem links
>   [ ] Outro. Deixe um comentário: ....

Cada opção teria uma consequência diferente:

1. A primeira opção é uma pegadinha. Mostraria uma mensagem de "vote no conteúdo e não na pessoa".
2. Uma notificação vai para o usuário dizendo que alguém considerou a resposta dele tecnicamente incorreta. Se o usuário deixar um comentário ele é adicionado à resposta.
3. Uma notificação vai para o usuário dizendo que alguém considerou a resposta dele incompleta. Se o usuário deixar um comentário ele é adicionado à resposta.
4. Uma notificação vai para o usuário sugerindo que ele melhore a formatação. Uma mensagem é exibida para quem votou dizendo: "Você também pode ajudar a comunidade melhorando o conteúdo de perguntas e respostas. Basta usar a opção editar."
5. Sugere adicionar uma sinalização, além de notificar o usuário.
6. Sugere adicionar uma sinalização, além de notificar o usuário.
7. Tenta persuadir o usuário a deixar um comentário para explicar o negativo.

Em alguns casos, o voto negativo poderia ser revertido numa sinalização ou voto para fechar. Isso é bom principalmente para perguntas que são interessantes e bem-feitas, mas mesmo assim recebem negativos por "não estarem dentro das regras", o que para mim não faz sentido, já que existe o fechamento para lidar com isso.

## Burocracia e Obrigatoriedade

Claro que isso seria interessante, mas vejo também o outro lado, isto é, de aumentar grandemente a burocracia para votar.

Provavelmente usuários mais ativos vão ficar de "saco cheio" de ver popups com questionário brotando a todo momento.

Para contornar isso, vejo algumas opções principais:

- Questionário é sempre exibido, mas com um método fácil de não responder. Um botão cancelar bem visível e talvez a tecla de atalho <kbd>ESC</kbd> fecham o questionário
- Usuários com pontuação maior que X podem inibir permanentemente o questionário
- Não exibir o questionário mais do que X vezes por dia ou em casos onde ele já foi aplicado a várias pessoas

## O que fazer com essa informação

Assim como hoje os usuários com alguns privilégios podem ver quando votos positivos e negativos, um novo item seria adicionado mostrando a opinião dos votos. Poderia ser uma tabelinha simples ou um gráfico de torta.

Além disso, essa informação poderia ser exibida para o autor do conteúdo de forma que ele pudesse ver o que em geral as pessoas acharam.

Para não encher o usuário de notificações, elas poderiam ser colocadas numa fila e, caso haja mais de um tipo, uma mensagem genérica com o link para o gráfico seria exibida para ele. Por exemplo:

> Alguns usuários sugerem que você poderia melhorar sua resposta. Veja o feedback recebido aqui...

E segue o link para uma nova página, mostrando, por exemplo:

> 70% dos usuários consideraram que a resposta está incompleta.
>   30% dos usuários consideraram que a formatação da resposta deveria ser melhorada.
>
> Editando a sua resposta, os usuários que votaram serão notificados para que eles tenham a chance de revisar sua edição.

Comment: A ideia não é dificultar o voto errado, principalmente o negativo? Então a burocracia é boa. Claro que a experiência tem que ser boa, o sistema tem que procurar evitar o exagero, a redundância. Tem várias regras que precisam ser aplicadas para que seja mais útil que estorvo. Todas essas coisas seriam apreciadas.

Comment: Gostei da ideia, desde que continue não sendo obrigatório identificar que foi você quem negativou,pois tem usuários que se sentem atacados quando recebem negativos(como se isso fosse pra "agredi-los" de alguma forma) e retaliam com serial downvote(é revertido, mas é chato quando o ocorre e nem sempre devolve 100% dos votos, ainda mais se coincidir mais de uma pessoa). Um dos motivos que me inibiram de justificar negativos foram esses.

Comment: Gostei muitíssimo da ideia. Sobre a burocracia, ela vai custar essencialmente um ou dois cliques a mais (até porque, alguém que realmente se preocupa com o conteúdo já deixa o comentário de qualquer forma, então esse "esforço" eu não conto como parte de uma "nova burocracia"). Pra melhorar para usuários experientes, eu acho que a alternativa do ESC é a melhor, mas depende de qual opção vai ser marcada como padrão (default). Se usar "outro: deixe comentário", a interação vai ter apenas um ESC a mais.

Comment: Sobre a "pegadinha", talvez fosse importante deixar o usuário votar assim mesmo, se ele realmente desejar. Sei que não é uma coisa correta, mas o direito a voto, hoje, é individual. Além disso, usuários que talvez usem isso para "o jogo", iam simplesmente aprender como o sistema funciona e mentir na escolha. Como forma de medição, é mais importante deixar votar assim e simplesmente armazenar as escolhas. Ou seja, exibiria-se a mensagem dizendo "Você não deveria votar no usuário, e sim no conteúdo", mas manteria o voto assim mesmo.

Comment: Muito boa ideia, só acho que devias esclarecer melhor o que é para respostas e para perguntas, porque ora falas de perguntas como de seguida de respostas.

Comment: @LuizVieira mesmo tentando burlar fica mais fácil identificar a má intenção. Tem vários detalhes que precisariam ser discutidos sobre isto, mas só vale quando a SE disser "estamos pensando em implementar isso, vamos discutir os detalhes".

Comment: @bigown Concordo. :)

Comment: Muito boa ideia, sugiro algo como http://i.stack.imgur.com/sNItV.png, para notificações deste tipo. O que o @LuizVieira falou sobre manter a pegadinha, é bom para saber quantos usuários pensam assim, e também facilita na hora de reversões, podendo no futuro estabelecer graficos de mudança de atitude.

Comment: Isso de computar o voto mesmo que seja por picuinha pessoal eu discordo enfaticamente! Respeito como parte do processo criativo de imaginar melhorias para um problema real, mas o importante, o essencial do voto é classificar o conteúdo, não nos esqueçamos disso. Quando um cara vota por que não gosta de quem respondeu isso é péssimo para a classificação de conteúdo. Se for uma resposta boa, melhor do que qualquer fonte na internet, mas não for uma resposta ampla e canônica (ou quase), dessas que atraem muitos votos, vai ter um, dois, três votos.

Comment: Então imagina o estrago que um cara votando assim pode causar. Entendo que teriam outras formas de evitar depois, com advertência e até suspensão, mas acho que permitir que um cara expresse essa finalidade de voto e o sistema aceitar isso com um "Olha, você não deveria..., mas tudo bem vai, destila aí o seu ódio". Como depois (quantas vezes iria aceitar isso?)   você vai advertir o cara? Ele vai dizer: Ah mas eu pensei que era do jogo! O sistema aceitou, achei que tudo bem.... Voto pela mensagem de resposta: "Qual seu problema cara, você é idiota?".

Comment: Vejo muitas questões em que me parece que os votos negativos são dados sem motivo nenhum, já vi perguntas com todas as características de uma pergunta válida sobre o contexto do "SO", porém recebeu voto negativo. Na minha opinião o usuário deveria saber o motivo de ter recebido um voto negativo.

Answer (score -4):

Na minha opinião todo voto negativo deveria vir com o comentario sobre o porque do voto.

Estava agora olhando na wikipedia sobre o stack e o que foi resumido foi o seguinte. Um site de perguntas e respostas, ja vi muitas respostas negativadas e que resolveram o problema de muitos.

O que entendo é que não precisa ser catedratico no assunto para poder expressar o que você acha que pode solicionar o problema ou até mesmo passar alguma coisa que possa resolver o problema não importando se o usuario com dificuldade vai entender para o que serve ou não aquilo que passou pra ele. Mas se caso quem responder tiver conhecimento sobre o assunto não é só valido como é até uma cortesia de alto valor.( quanto mais completa a resposta mais ponto vale) (uma resposta que resolva o problema mesmo que não seja ensinativa , não merece um voto negativo)

Comment: Até concordo com alguns casos ter que haver justificativa, mas entenda que a maioria do casos justificar é tão redundante que só gera burocracia, muitas postagens tem os motivos quase óbvios do porque recebem downvote ou upvote, o problema REAL é outro, tem gente pensando que tem separação entre usuário experiente e novato, achando que quem ganha up ou down é por questão de tempo na comunidade (ou score), **mas não é**, o problema é que muitos veem aqui e não entedem e não leem o [MODELO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange) do site, então acabam achando muita coisa injusta...

Comment: ...mas isso é um mero engano e os problemas não são as supostas "regras", o problema é que na verdade poucos se interessam em entender a comunidade e começam a se achar injustiçados, recomendo que leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4871/3635 ... Espero que entenda como um **critica construtiva** ;)