# Critérios de fechamento deveriam ser explícitos?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, qualidade, experiência

> Esta postagem se originou [desta resposta original](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4848/73), como parte da
>   discussão a respeito de como melhorar a percepção dos usuários com
>   relação às experiências ruins no site. Por favor, dê a sua opinião a
>   respeito desta sugestão particular.

**Critérios de fechamento deveriam ser explícitos**. Outra questão importante do ponto de vista da experiência é que as injustiças não são facilmente perceptíveis. No caso dos votos não há mesmo justificativa (e nem deveria - essa é outra discussão), mas nos fechamentos há justificativas que são simplesmente escondidas. Parece-me terrivelmente ruim o fato de que não importa a justificativa que eu escolhi para votar no fechamento de uma pergunta, a que aparece para o usuário é aquela que teve mais votos. Já houve casos em que uma pergunta deveria ser fechada (na minha opinião) como não clara, e muitas outras pessoas votaram nela como fora do escopo. Bom, se em 5 votos apenas o meu foi diferente, talvez eu esteja errado. Mas, e se 3 pessoas votaram em coisas totalmente distintas e outros 2 votaram no mesmo item, faz mesmo sentido a pergunta ser fechada indicando esse item (que os 2 votaram) como a razão? O fato de não haver concordância no motivo do fechamento deveria ser um indicativo de que há problemas maiores nessa pergunta. Assim, mesmo que para o autor da postagem aparecesse apenas o motivo com mais votos, deveria ser possível a todos consultar a qualquer momento quais foram os motivos individuais de sugestão de fechamento. Talvez fosse interessante também que questões fechadas sem uma concordância razoável fossem enviadas para uma fila de análise ou que necessitassem de mais votos.

Comment: Acho que poderia aplicar um texto mais genérico contendo um link onde poderia ser visto em detalhes os motivos individualmente. Exemplo: "Esta pergunta foi fechada, veja os motivos aqui". Algo desse tipo.

Comment: Deveria ser melhor explicado em todos os sentidos. Deveria gerar notificação. Essas são ideias já apresentadas no MSE e ou a SE disse não ou nada foi feito mesmo depois de anos. Então acho pouco provável que mude depois de postado aqui.

Comment: @bigown tem links desses?