# O voto para fechar não deveria ser enviesado apenas para o lado negativo?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, qualidade, experiência

> Esta postagem se originou [desta resposta original](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4848/73), como parte da
>   discussão a respeito de como melhorar a percepção dos usuários com
>   relação às experiências ruins no site. Por favor, dê a sua opinião a
>   respeito desta sugestão particular.

**O voto para fechar não deveria ser enviesado apenas para o lado negativo**. Muitas vezes a comunidade vota para fechar uma pergunta que eu acho que tem salvação, mas eu não tenho como questionar até que a pergunta seja fechada e eu vote para reabrir. Alternativamente eu posso abrir uma questão no meta, mas há de se perceber que o Meta é um tanto exclusivo (não são todos os membros que participam). O fato é que uma vez que uma pergunta é votada para fechar, ela tem ali um marcador (uma setinha de votos) similar ao da votação normal, mas apenas pra baixo. A estigmergia funciona, atraindo novos votantes, mas ninguém é capaz de votar em oposição. Talvez fosse interessante exibir uma opção para votar como "manter aberta", opção essa que seria exibida a partir do momento em que a primeira pessoa votasse para fechar. Uma pergunta que tivesse menos votos para fechar do que para manter aberta certamente não deveria ser fechada (sem qualquer discussão necessária). Isso pode ser bom ou ruim, claro, dependendo do uso que as pessoas fazem. Mas, certamente parece mais justo ao autor do conteúdo envolvido.

Comment: Concordo. Uma opção de voto contrário como "manter aberta", seria uma opção legal.

Comment: Não vejo nada de negativo nisso, eis minha opinião do porque devemos votar pra fechar http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635

Comment: Se o sistema for feito de forma adequada pode até fechar de cara no primeiro voto. Porque outro problema que eu acho até maior é a pergunta demorar muito p/ ser fechada, receber respostas que não servem ali. Aí a pergunta é salva, mas as respostas que estão ali ficam inválidas. A discussão sobre isso não pode deixar de olhar para este problema real. A forma atual, apesar do discurso ser de poder reabrir, é de dificultar o fechamento e reabertura. O sistema poderia ser mais voltado para evitar logo que a pergunta ande em estado ruim e que após recuperada seja fácil "reabilitá-la"

Comment: @bigown É verdade, esse problema parece realmente mais impactante porque pode afetar a experiência de qualquer usuário (não apenas novatos), por envolver tempo gasto preparando respostas que podem se tornar inválidas. Mas, por outro lado, a indicação de que uma pergunta está recebendo votos para fechar não devia fazer um potencial respondente esperar um pouco antes de responder? Você mesmo sempre foi crítico de respostas boas terem que validar perguntas, não?

Comment: @LuizVieira em geral, em acho que sim, mas aí vamos entrar na discussão do que é o ideal e o como os humanos se comportam, o que eu acho que compreende até melhor que a média. Eu acho que a experiência, acima de tudo, deve ser melhorada. Ações secundárias podem ser tomadas quando a experiência não consegue atingir o objetivo por si só. Sou crítico a isto, mas não fortemente, se a resposta valida, ele pode ser a salvação da pergunta. Assim como eu acho que precisa ter melhores e mais eficazes mecanismos de filtrar conteúdo ruim, aí podemos negativar e fechar menos. Sou a favor de salvar mais.

Comment: Não sei se é impressão minha, mas mesmo com a várias repetições e comentários e conversas e tudo isso, ainda tem gente que pensa que fechar é algo definitivo, veja a resposta deletada do Junior: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4861/3635 ... Fora alguns que vieram discutir no chat sobre achar injusto o fechamento tão rápido. Não sei qual o pensamento da maioria, mas se o sistema permite reabrir e tem uma mensagem no rodapé da pergunta fechada de como reabrir acho que fica um tanto quanto claro que fechar não é definitivo....

Comment: ... Acho que os unicos fechamentos que quase sempre serão definitivos são: "Duplicatas" e "Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação", os demais quase sempre podem ser reabertos.