# Votos negativos em uma pergunta

Tags: debate, perguntas, voto-contra

Eu queria entender porque dar votos negativos em uma pergunta.

O intuito do site é para que pessoas com conhecimento e experiência maior em programação e áreas afins possam ajudar quem não tem todo esse conhecimento, porém algumas pessoas vêm a necessidade em dar votos negativos em uma pergunta.

Não é porque a pergunta é simples demais pra você que pra outra pessoa tem que ser também, nem todo mundo é expert, e o pior é que não tem nenhuma explicação de porque o voto negativo. Se não quer responder, não gostou da pergunta, só não responde, agora pra que atrapalhar a pessoa que está ali tentando aprender algo?

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4701/quando-usar-o-downvote

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu entendo, tem gente que comenta falando "Poxa sua perguntar está estranha, pode tentar editar pra ficar melhor de entender", agora muitos somente dão o voto negativo e você fica sem saber o porquê. Tem uma pergunta minha que até você respondeu e me ajudou bastante, porém a pergunta tem 7 votos negativos, e não sei porque.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241133/cor-estranha-nas-tags-php-no-sublime?noredirect=1#comment493787_241133

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu entendo o uso, acho até que é necessário ter o voto negativo, mas ainda acho que deviria ter uma forma de a pessoa saber o porque, eu posso olhar pra pergunta que eu fiz várias vezes e não ver onde está o problema que está causando os downvotes entende! Okay, fico no aguardo!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Só mais essa minha que recebeu votos negativos e ela está marcada como pendente, o que seria isso?
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240382/sistema-de-login-dando-erro

Comment: Tanto pra você @ArthurOliveira quanto para qualquer outro usuário que chegar aqui, recomendo que leia isto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2673/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi, e tem como eu fechar a pergunta? Eu tentei excluir mas fala que como outra pessoa respondeu não pode ser excluída.

Comment: @ArthurOliveira a segunda tem resposta, não dá pra ser excluida, a primeira você pode excluir, mas não precisa se preocupar com isto, perguntas sem respostas aceitas e/ou respostas com score infeior a "1" são removidas sozinhas e os seus pontos são devolvidos, acho que são 7 dias pra remover.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Saquei, muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda, desculpa qualquer coisa!!

Comment: @ArthurOliveira imagina e *Seja Bem Vindo ao SOpt!* :D

Comment: No meu ver você fez duas coisas que quem pergunta não deve fazer, e que são possíveis motivos para ser negativado. Postar o código em imagem e não indicar o erro que disse que dava.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essa pergunta:

[Cor estranha nas tags php no Sublime!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241133/3635)

Tem 2 votos de fechamento, um meu outro de outro usuário, isto porque ela se enquadra no tipo de problema já descrito no Modal de fechamento e Help:

> Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável.

### O que isto quer dizer?

Este tipo de fechamento indica no seu caso especifico que a pergunta não é útil a ninguém futuro porque foi **"erro de digitação"**, como está na própria descrição:

> ...sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro...

Ou seja não é uma falha de configuração de software, uma duvida de como fazer ou coisa do tipo, então a sua pergunta não se enquadra nas perguntas on-topic, link do Help:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

A única maneira de perguntas assim serem úteis para alguém é se coincidentemente alguém em outro lugar fizer um código idêntico ao seu com o mesmo erro e na mesma linha.

### Motivos do downvote

Downvotes não são do "mal" nem do "bem", cada um usa a sua maneira, claro que existe o método ideal que alguns da comunidades acreditam, que particularmente creio ser parecida com a minha visão:

> Votos sejam para baixo ou cima devem ser usados para avaliar as postagens e não as pessoas, mostrando que é útil e de preferencia que tenha um conhecimento minimo ao menos no que vai votar
>
> **Para mais detalhes** (e/ou outras visões de como usar o downvote) leia:
>
> - [Quando usar o downvote](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4701/3635)

Perguntas com voto de fechamento geralmente recebem downvotes, isso seria uma maneira de dar enfase para outros usuários que ali na pergunta tem um problema grave, mas como nem todos podem votar pra fechar, é necessário um score um pouco elevado pra ter está opção habilitada, então muitos não podem votar pra fechar, eles preferem então colaborar apontando que ali tem falha fazendo o uso do downvote.

### O porque das pessoas não comentarem aonde esta a falha

As pessoas no caso da sua pergunta comentaram, claro que não dá pra afirmar que foram os usuários ali que deram o downvote, qualquer um pode votar e ficar anonimo. Comentar é opcional e geralmente as pessoas evitam comentar porque as vezes acabam sofrendo algum tipo de perseguição, isso porque cada pessoa é uma, cada um tem um grau de maturidade, tem gente que entende como critica construtiva e tem gente que simplesmente pensa que é um ataque pessoal e começam a negativar gratuitamente quem as negativou primeiro.

Por esse motivo eu digo, vote pela qualidade da postagem (perguntas e resposta) e não pela pessoa.

Comment: Entendi, eu até entendo que no caso dessa minha pergunta não é útil pra outras pessoas, mas pra mim foi muito, porque eu estava desde cedo tentando encontrar o problema, mas eu não enxerguei que faltava um parêntese ali. Tem muitas pessoas, que como eu, começaram a aprender agora, não tem experiência nenhuma, e quando faz uma pergunta e já recebe tantos votos negativos, faz querer não perguntar mais nada sabe. Mas eu entendo a necessidade dos votos, só queria entender um pouco mais sobre!

Comment: @ArthurOliveira Então legal essa curiosidade, é saudável entender, mas a questão que quero deixar claro é que **não** é questão de *tão* (em quantidade), mas sim de ser um erro pessoal seu que nunca vai se repetir, a não ser que coincidentemente alguém escreva um código idêntico ao seu com a mesma falha na mesma linha. Entende?