# É errado fazer perguntas para promover o Stack Overflow?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Gostaria de saber se é errado fazer perguntas com o **intuito** de promover o site. Por exemplo:

Acredito que a pergunta "X", pode acrescentar bastante no site, gerar respostas produtivas e até servir como uma das referências principais quando procuradas no Google. Um exemplo disso foi uma pergunta que fiz aqui no Stack Overflow:

[Existe classe em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108548/existe-classe-em-javascript)

Se digitarem no Google "classe em javascript", o link para essa pergunta é a quarta referência na primeira página (isso hoje, dia 22/01/2016), o que acredito que possa ser uma referência muito boa, além de aumentar as chances de pessoas ingressarem e aumentarem tanto em quantidade como em qualidade aqui na comunidade.

O que gostaria de saber de maneira bem clara é se a pergunta pode ser feita apenas para promover a comunidade, mesmo que quem pergunte, já saiba ou tenha alguma opinião sobre a resposta.

Gostaria de deixar claro que a pergunta tem como finalidade promover o Stack Overflow, e nenhuma das marcadas como semelhantes ou possíveis duplicadas fazem sentido em serem sinalizadas assim.

Comment: Acho ótimo pra ter uma fonte de pesquisa mais confiavel e de fácil atualização (comunitária) que é diferente dos blogs aonde o numero de pessoas que colocam "dicas" e "tutoriais" é limitado (geralmente ao proprietário).

Comment: **Não é errado, isso é positivo e incentivado.** Como disse o @GuilhermeNascimento, o critério é que a pergunta seja adequada ao site.

Comment: Eu concordo que seria bom, e realmente vale um debate, pois como diz o próprio title do **downvote**: '**Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa;** ela não é clara ou não é útil', e a meu entender seria falta de esforço de pesquisa. Por isso seria interessante por o que ja foi pesquisado, e disser o que necessita melhorar. Ou altera o title e pronto :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert o titulo me parece bom o suficiente neste caso, mas tem realmente muitas perguntas com titulos ruins. Sempre edito estes casos (os que eu vejo)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não creio ser apenas uma questão de títulos, se o corpo da pergunta não tiver um bom embasamento, de nada adianta tem um titulo bom. [Esta pergunta por exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7/operador-e-em-javascript), tanto titulo como corpo, ao meu ver mostra falta de pesquisa, mas a comunidade gosta, eu também acho interessante, pois agregar conteúdo, mas se for seguir a risca o que diz o title comentado anteriomente, deveria ser um pergunta ruim.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert sim concordo, mas eu não estava falando do contexto geral, estava apenas citando um trecho do seu comentário anterior: *Ou altera o title e pronto* ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o *Ou altera o title e pronto* seria o title do downvote, não da pergunta. Seria em relação ao SO. Creio haver discrepância entre o que a comunidade acha correto e algumas regras.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Ah entendi outra coisa... Sobre a discrepância, geralmente quem forma as regras é a comunidade, não?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento teoricamente sim :D , mas supondo que eu seja um usuário novo, e leia o title **Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa**, eu irei definir isso como critério inicial para meu voto, a comunidade em si aceita esse tipo de pergunta, mas eu ainda não sei disso. Logo *downvote*.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Yep! você está comentando um problema que eu vivo citando no Chat! É isso mesmo, muito mal uso do downvote. Tem vezes que as pessoas nem votam pra fechar apenas dão downvotes :/ - Até acho que pode usar da maneira que quiser, afinal cada um decide o que faz por si só com os downvotes, mas a falta de fechamento e a falta de entendimento das regras da comunidade é um problema realmente longe de ser solucionado. Concordo absolutamente contigo.

Comment: Pra mim, o termo informado aparece essa unica pergunta do SOPT nas primeiras paginas http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1920/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-criar-uma-classe-abstrata-em-javascript

Comment: Não vejo mau algum e fazer uma pergunta simples, se a pergunta for bem elaborada ira render ótimas respostas, perguntas assim ajudam usuários que estão aprendendo e sem falar que faz o SOpt aparecer em primeiro nas pequisas, já que as perguntas simples é as que geram respostas amplas e são as mais procuradas por iniciantes.

Comment: há várias peguntas sobre o mesmo assunto. Eu mesmo tinha feito uma logo quando comecei a participar aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2170/quest%C3%A3o-simples-demais-feita-por-um-experiente

Comment: Daniel, a pergunta que coloquei, está falando em promover o stackoverflow. Todas que você relacionou não tem a mesma dúvida com a pergunta que fiz, podem ser parecidas em alguns pontos, mas são diferentes.

Comment: A pergunta em si pode não ser exatamente igual a outras existentes. Contudo, as respostas serão iguais as das perguntas similares. Pesquise um pouco mais e encontrará dezenas de perguntas iguais ou similares, todas com as mesmas respostas. Os links que postei aqui são meramente exemplos pequenos do que pode encontrar relacionado ao tema. Leia o conteúdo tal como os comentários e respostas e entenderá que esse assunto é duplicado.

Comment: Confira a meta-tag [meta-tag:responder-a-si-mesmo] -tem poucas perguntas- se por acaso achar que alguma delas responde a esta sua pergunta, não tem problema marcar esta como duplicata. Igual que no site principal, as duplicatas servem como alternativa na hora de fazer search.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim. Você pode fazer isso. Mas cuidado...

Na realidade o objetivo do site é ter uma coleção de perguntas e respostas **úteis**.

Então a questão sempre vai girar em torno de se a sua pergunta é realmente útil e entra [no escopo do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Não importa se é [uma pergunta fácil de ser respondida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/%C3%89-errado-perguntar-por-coisas-que-se-acham-facilmente-como-alguns-julgam-no-go). Se é uma pergunta do formato aceito no site, [bem preparada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), clara e objetiva, não importa se você já sabe a resposta. Na verdade, você mesmo pode até [responder a sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responder-a-si-mesmo).

O cuidado então é que não importa a motivação. O que importa é a pergunta em si.

Comment: Legal, excelente compilação de links

Comment: Excelente! Isso mesmo!

Comment: show de bola! Todos os comentários e a resposta esclareceram totalmente minha dúvida!