# O que fazer com respostas/comentários de má vontade?

Tags: debate, comunidade, respostas, comentários

O que fazer com resposta do tipo: `olhe a documentação`, `pesquise no google`, `estude mais sobre *`, etc?

Comment: Relacionada:[É errado perguntar por coisas que se acham facilmente (como alguns julgam) no Google?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4432/28595)

Comment: Como o bigown disse, orientar que isto não é construtivo. Todavia existem usuários que vão levar a mal, então ao invés de entrar em um debate sem necessidade com estes tipos de usuários, apenas ignore-os. Acredite a maior parte da comunidade entende o que é construtivo, esses exemplo que você citou são apenas algumas exceções "infelizes" :)

Comment: Sempre tem uns caras abusados aqui que vem e posta: "Respondam essas perguntas pra mim com explicação" ou vem pedir um código pronto. Mas no meu caso eu sempre pesquiso bastante e quando vejo que não consigo mesmo eu peço ajuda. E é desanimador vir alguém e te manda ler mais ou coisa do tipo. Da mesma forma que eu ajudo as pessoas também espero ser ajudado quando preciso. Não é justo sair comentando esse tipo de coisa assumindo que a pessoa é um preguiçoso que postou sem pesquisar. Quem não tiver paciência de ajudar é só não responder, é o que eu penso, e estão no lugar errado Vlws rsrs

Comment: Sim, mas sempre terão usuários que não entendem o proposito do site, outro dia um rapaz me respondeu algo que não tinha nada haver com o que eu perguntei, eu fui explicar pra ele que não era o ponto e então ele começou um "showzinho" de "sou vitima" e "o guilherme (eu) é do mal" e até abriu uma pergunta no Meta pra reclamar de mim, isso porque eu falei, eu tentei argumentar com ele, mas não deu, então a solução é ignorar mesmo e dar atenção aos usuários que tem boa vontade em lhe ajudar de verdade, se você se sentir ofendido com qualquer comentário por parte de alguem basta usar o Sinalizar ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Orientar a pessoa que isto não ajuda em nada e não deve ser feito e sinalizar como não construtivo ou não é uma resposta.